# How to pass arguments to functions in React js?

Tags: reactjs

1. I want to display person's email in the alert window. But, I do not know how to pass email as arguments to displayAlert method. Also, it wont let me use  either. So, I have to assign displayAlert methos to a variable and use it in onClick. I do not know why it wont let me call it directly.

   ```
   class People extends React.Component{
   render (){
           var handleClick = this.displayAlert;
           var items = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
               return(
                   <ul key = {item.id}>
                       <li>
                           <button onClick= {handleClick}>{item.lastName + ', ' + item.firstName}</button>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               )
           });
           return (<div>{items}</div>);
    }

   displayAlert (){
       alert('Hi');
   }
   }

    class PersonList extends React.Component{
        render () {
           return (
       <div>
           <People items={this.props.people}/> /* People is an array of people*/
       </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**The ES6 way**:

Using arrow functions `=>`

```
const items = this.props.items.map((item) => (
  <ul key={item.id}>
    <li>
      <button onClick={() => this.displayAlert(item.email)}>
        {item.lastName + ', ' + item.firstName}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
));
```

`onClick` the anonymous function is called and executes `this.displayAlert(item.email)`

**The ES5 way:**

You could do this using [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and passing the parameter in there.

You should also pass `this` or use bind to keep the proper context on your `.map` function:

```
var items = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
  return (
    <ul key={item.id}>
      <li>
        <button onClick={this.displayAlert.bind(this, item.email)}>
          {item.lastName + ', ' + item.firstName}
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}, this);
```

Shown in the example here: [React - Communicate Between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)

Comment: Please do not create functions within component `props`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677798/434697

Comment: Using an arrow function you're creating a new function each time, which has performance effects

Answer (score 4):

Using arrow function and babel plugin "transform-class-properties"

```
class People extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.props.items.map( (item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <button onClick={this.displayAlert(item)}>
              {item.lastName + ', ' + item.firstName}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  displayAlert = (item) => (event) => {
    // you can access the item object and the event object
    alert('Hi');
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to add to pass another object let say a string along with item?