# Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, arrow-functions

I'm running lint with my React app, and I receive this error:

```
error    JSX props should not use arrow functions        react/jsx-no-bind
```

And this is where I'm running the arrow function (inside `onClick`):

```
{this.state.photos.map(tile => (
  <span key={tile.img}>
    <Checkbox
      defaultChecked={tile.checked}
      onCheck={() => this.selectPicture(tile)}
      style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 99, padding: 5, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72)'}}
    />
    <GridTile
      title={tile.title}
      subtitle={<span>by <b>{tile.author}</b></span>}
      actionIcon={<IconButton onClick={() => this.handleDelete(tile)}><Delete color="white"/></IconButton>}
    >
      <img onClick={() => this.handleOpen(tile.img)} src={tile.img} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}/>
    </GridTile>
  </span>
))}
```

Is this a bad practice that should be avoided? And what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

**Why you shouldn't use inline arrow functions in JSX props**

Using arrow functions or binding in JSX is a bad practice that hurts performance, because the function is recreated on each render.

1. Whenever a function is created, the previous function is garbage collected. Rerendering many elements might create jank in animations.
2. Using an inline arrow function will cause `PureComponent`s, and components that use `shallowCompare` in the `shouldComponentUpdate` method to rerender anyway. Since the arrow function prop is recreated each time, the shallow compare will identify it as a change to a prop, and the component will rerender.

As you can see in the following 2 examples - when we use inline arrow function, the `<Button>` component is rerendered each time (the console shows the 'render button' text).

*Example 1 - PureComponent **without** inline handler*

```js
class Button extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    
    console.log('render button');
    
    return (
      <button onClick={ onClick }>Click</button>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }
  
  onClick = () => this.setState((prevState) => ({
    counter: prevState.counter + 1
  }));
  
  render() {
    const { counter } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={ this.onClick } />
        <div>{ counter }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

*Example 2 - PureComponent **with** inline handler*

```js
class Button extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    
    console.log('render button');
    
    return (
      <button onClick={ onClick }>Click</button>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }
  
  render() {
    const { counter } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={ () => this.setState((prevState) => ({
          counter: prevState.counter + 1
        })) } />
        <div>{ counter }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Binding methods to `this` without inlining arrow functions**

1. Binding the method manually in the constructor:

   ```
   class Button extends React.Component {
     constructor(props, context) {
       super(props, context);

       this.cb = this.cb.bind(this);
     }

     cb() {

     }

     render() {
       return (
         <button onClick={ this.cb }>Click</button>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. Binding a method using the [proposal-class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) with an arrow function. As this is  a stage 3 proposal, you'll need to add the [Stage 3 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/) or the [Class properties transform](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to your babel configuration.

   ```
   class Button extends React.Component {
     cb = () => { // the class property is initialized with an arrow function that binds this to the class

     }

     render() {
       return (
         <button onClick={ this.cb }>Click</button>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

### Function Components with inner callbacks

When we create an inner function (event handler for example) inside a function component, the function will be recreated every time the component is rendered. If the function is passed as props (or via context) to a child component (`Button` in this case), that child will re-render as well.

*Example 1 - Function Component with an inner callback:*

```js
const { memo, useState } = React;

const Button = memo(({ onClick }) => console.log('render button') || (
  <button onClick={onClick}>Click</button>
));

const Parent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  const increment = () => setCounter(counter => counter + 1); // the function is recreated all the time
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={increment} />
      
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

To solve this problem, we can wrap the callback with the [`useCallback()` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), and set the dependencies to an empty array.

**Note:** the `useState` generated function accepts an updater function, that provides the current state. In this way, we don't need to set the current state a dependency of `useCallback`.

*Example 2 - Function Component with an inner callback wrapped with useCallback:*

```js
const { memo, useState, useCallback } = React;

const Button = memo(({ onClick }) => console.log('render button') || (
  <button onClick={onClick}>Click</button>
));

const Parent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  const increment = useCallback(() => setCounter(counter => counter + 1), []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={increment} />
      
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How do you achieve this on stateless components?

Comment: Stateless (function) components don't have `this`, so there's nothing to bind. Usually the methods are supplied by a wrapper smart component.

Comment: Makes sense. I have some stateless components that dispatch actions to redux, but via arrow funcs in the component, not via props passed in. Seems like I could refactor to pass in the function instead and gain some perf. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Use react-redux and `mapDispatchToProps` in the smart component created by `connect` to create the functions you pass to props.

Comment: I do actually, but come to think of it, I never just provide the callback in the `onClick`, I always bind to an arrow function out of habit, thinking it would be invoked immediately otherwise. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @OriDrori: How does that work when you need to pass data in the callback? `onClick={() => { onTodoClick(todo.id) }`

Comment: @adam-beck - add it inside the callback method definition in the class `cb() { onTodoClick(this.props.todo.id); }`.

Comment: This is the lowest level I have and it's just a stateless component. Is this what you meant? https://gist.github.com/adam-beck/686bd0e4f495abcbbdcd0fab41f68eb6

Comment: Use a class component, and use one of it's methods as the callback. The CB then will be able to use one of the class properties as id.

Comment: In my test right now class instance arrow functions are not bound to `this`.

Comment: Indeed they are not. You should bind them manually by using one of the methods in the answer.

Comment: would `constructor(props) { this.onTodoClick = () => this.props.onTodoClick(this.props.id) }` do work also?

Comment: @philk - Indeed. It's equivalent to declaring Class Instance Fields.

Comment: @OriDrori but is it considered bad style, or why I never see that in tutorials and examples?

Comment: No idea, but maybe class properties, and bind in the constructor preserve the class format, ie methods in the class body, while the method you presented moves everything to the constructor. However, I'm just guessing.

Comment: "Rerendering many elements might create jank in animations." Does this apply to animations done using JS only or also to CSS animations?

Comment: Garbage collection might effect both types of animations as far as I know.

Comment: @adam-beck - I've added a solution using hooks that addresses the passing data in the callback question.

Comment: @adam-beck I think this is how to use `useCallback` with dynamic value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006061/react-hooks-usecallback-with-parameters-inside-loop

Comment: You can check list of items section here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#lists-of-items. Gives a nice example of how to proceed when there is a need to pass data

Comment: This is a major generalization, inline functions as props are not inherently bad as Ryan Florence illustrates in this post https://medium.com/@ryanflorence/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

Answer (score 21):

Using inline functions like this is perfectly fine. The linting rule is outdated.

This rule is from a time when arrow functions were not as common and people used .bind(this), which used to be slow. The performance issue has been fixed in Chrome 49.

Do pay attention that you do not pass inline functions as props to a child component.

Ryan Florence, the author of React Router, has written a great piece about this:

https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-inline-functions-and-performance/

Comment: Can you please show how to write a unit test on components with inline arrow functions? ˆˆ

Comment: @krankuba This is not what this question was about. You can still pass in anonymous functions that are not defined inline but are still not testable.

Comment: This is link https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-inline-functions-and-performance

Comment: @sbaechler - I agree with almost all of the answer, but can we not call the rule outdated - it is still useful in guarding against arrow functions being passed in props.

Answer (score 15):

#### Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?

Mostly, because inline functions can break memoization of optimized components:

> Traditionally, performance concerns around inline functions in React have been related to how passing new callbacks on each render breaks `shouldComponentUpdate` optimizations in child components. ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render))

It is less about additional function creation cost:

> Performance issues with `Function.prototype.bind` [got fixed here](http://benediktmeurer.de/2015/12/25/a-new-approach-to-function-prototype-bind/) and arrow functions are either a native thing or are transpiled by babel to plain functions; in both cases we can assume it’s not slow. ([React Training](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578))
>
> I believe people claiming function creation is expensive have always been misinformed (React team never said this). ([Tweet](https://twitter.com/sophiebits/status/1069150849467731968))

#### When is the `react/jsx-no-bind` rule useful?

You want to ensure, that memoized components work as intended:

- `React.memo` (for function components)
- `PureComponent` or custom `shouldComponentUpdate` (for class components)

By obeying to this rule, stable function object references are passed. So above components can optimize performance by preventing re-renders, when previous props have not changed.

#### How to solve the ESLint error?

Classes: Define the handler as method, or [class property](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance) for `this` binding.
Hooks: Use [`useCallback`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#react-hooks).

#### Middleground

In many cases, inline functions are very convenient to use and absolutely fine in terms of performance requirements. Unfortunately, this rule cannot be limited to only memoized component types. If you still want to use it across-the-board, you could e.g. [disable it](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) for simple DOM nodes:

```
rules: {
  "react/jsx-no-bind": [ "error", { "ignoreDOMComponents": true } ],
}

const Comp = () => <span onClick={() => console.log("Hello!")} />; // no warning
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing the wording for the second last sentence. It gives the impression that you're talking about the concept itself, not the implementation of the eslint rule. If I totally missed your point, it again proves that your intention is not clear.

Answer (score 12):

This is because an arrow function apparently will create a new instance of the function on each render if used in a JSX property. This might create a huge strain on the garbage collector and will also hinder the browser from optimizing any "hot paths" since functions will be thrown away instead of reused.

You can see the whole explanation and some more info at https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Comment: Not only that. Creating the new function instances each time means the state is modified and when a component's state is modified it will be re-rendered. Since one of the main reasons to use React is to only render elements that change, using `bind` or arrow functions here is shooting yourself in the foot. It is **not** well documented though, especially in the case of working with `map`ping arrays within Lists, etc.

Comment: "Creating the new function instances each time means the state is modified"  what do you mean by that? There's no state in at all in the question

Answer (score 5):

You can remove this error by wrapping the function inside useCallback.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid creating new functions with the same arguments, you could memoize the function bind result, here is a simple utility named `memobind` to do it: https://github.com/supnate/memobind

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering when you need to pass data in the callback. Ex.:

```
const list = todos.map((todo, index) => (
  <Todo
    onClick={() => { onTodoClick(todo.id, todo.title, index) }
  />
));
```

### Solution

[According to the official documentation](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#lists-of-items), you should do:

1. Move the function arguments into the children component:

```
const list = todos.map((todo, index) => (
  <Todo
    onClick={onTodoClick}
    todoId={todo.id}
    todoTitle={todo.title}
    indexOnList={index}
  />
));
```

2. In the children component (`<Todo />`), pass the arguments in the call:

```
function Todo(props) {
  // component properties
  const { onClick, todoId, todoTitle, indexOnList } = props;

  // we move the call from the parent to the children
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    onClick(todoId, todoTitle, indexOnList);
  }, [todoId, todoTitle, indexOnList]);

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
    {/* the rest of the component remains the same */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Is this the best solution?

I dislike this solution. You end up with parent's data and logic in the children component. This makes the children component dependent on the parent component, breaking the dependency rule.

That's a big no-no for me.

What I do is just disable this rule. According to Ryan Florence (React Router author), this is not a big deal anyway:
https://medium.com/@ryanflorence/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

---

Answer (score 2):

The [new (in beta, jan 2023) React tutorial](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe) uses both functions and arrow functions as JSX props. This hints strongly at this not being a major concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions using [react-cached-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cached-handler) library, no need to be worried about re-rendering performance :

> Note : Internally it caches your arrow functions by the specified key,
> no need to be worried about re-rendering!

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.photos.map((photo) => (
                <Photo
                    key={photo.url}
                    onClick={this.handler(photo.url, (url) => {
                        console.log(url);
                    })}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Other features:**

- Named handlers
- Handle events by arrow functions
- Access to the key, custom arguments and the original event
- Component rendering performace
- Custom context for handlers

Comment: The question was why can't we use it. Not how to use it with some other hack.