# React Native component callback functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In components, I've seen different way of doing callbacks. What is the difference between:

```
<MyButton onPress={ () => {doSomething(data)} }>
```

and

```
<MyButton onPress={ this.doSomething.bind(this) }>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `<MyButton onPress={ () => {doSomething(data)} }>`

This code block uses the ES6 Arrow function; which is another way of declaring a function in javascript. Also, the scope of `this` in arrow function depend where the function was created as opposed to normal scoping rule of `this` which by default depends on *how the function was called*.

> `<MyButton onPress={ this.doSomething.bind(this) }>`

This statement makes a call to `doSomething` method. But since the event registration is done on different element, the Scope of `doSomething` is different and is forcefully binded by using `bind` method in javascript.

Also, in the second method you are not passing the data parameter, which you can pass using the second argument to the method like shown below.

`<MyButton onPress={ this.doSomething.bind(this, data)} }>`

Answer (score 5):

```
<MyButton onPress={ () => {doSomething(data)} }>
```

Is calling a new anonymous function `onPress`, which will run `doSomething`.

```
<MyButton onPress={ this.doSomething.bind(this) }>
```

Is calling a reference to a named function, that you have already defined in your class. The binding to this is required only when you are working with class function (I mean, non ES6 arrow function).

```
const doSomething = () => { ... }
```

Would not require a `.bind(this)`, since arrow functions bind on [lexical scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

You should definately read over [What is the best and most efficient way to bind callbacks in ReactJS? In the constructor or in the render method or as a property initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878280/what-is-the-best-and-most-efficient-way-to-bind-callbacks-in-reactjs-in-the-con/)