# Typescript and React refs without using inline lambdas

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The following quick example in TypeScript shows a way to get typed refs without using inline (which are suppose to be bad for performance). It is however rather ugly having to define two variables (`refAnimationWrapper` and `refAnimationWrapperHandler`) to define one ref. Does anyone have a simpler solution, could @decorators maybe be a solution?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

```html
import * as React from 'react';
import {TweenMax} from 'gsap';

export class TransitionDummy extends React.Component<any, any> {
    private transitionDuration = 0.4;

    private refAnimationWrapper:HTMLDivElement;
    private refAnimationWrapperHandler = (ref:HTMLDivElement) => this.refAnimationWrapper = ref;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    public componentWillEnter(done) {
        TweenMax.fromTo(this.refAnimationWrapper, this.transitionDuration, {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1, onComplete: done});
    }

    public componentWillLeave(done) {
        TweenMax.to(this.refAnimationWrapper, this.transitionDuration, {opacity: 0, onComplete: done});
    }
    
    public render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.refAnimationWrapperHandler}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is doing `<div ref={(input) => this.refAnimationWrapper = input}>` worse for performance than `<div ref={this.refAnimationWrapperHandler}>`?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I see people talking about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-jsx-props-should-not-use-arrow-functions). Personally, I wouldn't sacrifice code quality over saving a few micro seconds.

Comment: I just use inline lambdas https://medium.com/@basarat/strongly-typed-refs-for-react-typescript-9a07419f807#.t6092k5za

Comment: @DavidSherret I might end up taking this approach, I was just wondering if there was a way to get both. But probably the performance impact is minimal.

Comment: @basarat yeah, that was what I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap both of them in a class, that way each ref has one member:

```
class RefedElement<T> {
    wrapper: T;
    handler = (ref: T) => this.wrapper = ref;
}

export class TransitionDummy extends React.Component<any, any> {
    private transitionDuration = 0.4;

    private refAnimation: RefedElement<HTMLDivElement>;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.refAnimation = new RefedElement<HTMLDivElement>();
    }

    public componentWillEnter(done) {
        TweenMax.fromTo(this.refAnimation.wrapper, this.transitionDuration, {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1, onComplete: done});
    }

    public componentWillLeave(done) {
        TweenMax.to(this.refAnimation.wrapper, this.transitionDuration, {opacity: 0, onComplete: done});
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div ref={ this.refAnimation.handler }>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile for you, I'm getting: `Error:(21, 9) TS2322:Type 'RefedElement<{}>' is not assignable to type 'RefedElement<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.
    Property 'align' is missing in type '{}'.`

Comment: I also don't think this code saves much typing, other than if we could move the new RefedElement() call directly to the variable definition.

Comment: Right, it should be `new RefedElement<HTMLDivElement>()`, fixed in the answer. And it does save the amount of code once you have more than one "RefedElement".