# In Redux, when do I need to use .bind(this)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Sometimes I am really confused that when do I need to append `.bind(this)` to the method (ES5) or use arrow function (ES6)
e.g.

```
    handleSubmit(e) {
        console.log(this)
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(this)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-4">
                <form onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="user"/>
                    <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="comments"/>
                    <input type="submit" hidden/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

So if I want to access `this` inside `handleChange` and `handleSubmit`, then I have to use arrow function of `onChange` and `onSubmit`, otherwise the `onChange` and `onSubmit` can be changed as:

```
<form onChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

Am I right? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why JSX props should not use arrow functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-jsx-props-should-not-use-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to `.bind` each time when you pass your custom function to an event handler like `onChange` or `onSubmit`.

This is caused by the `this` context differences in React.createClass() vs extends React.Component.

Using React.createClass() will automatically bind this context (values) correctly, but that is not the case when using ES6 classes. When doing it the ES6 way (by extending React.Component) the  this context is `null` by default. Properties of the class do not automatically bind to the React class (component) instance.

Btw `.bind` is not the only option available. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41272784/1333836) for a summary to all approaches I know.

PS: This is not a Redux specific thing, actually - nothing to do with how Redux works. That's a pure ReactJS related behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, of course if you mean that `this` is the context of your class. In my opinion using `.bind` in these cases is more clear, but I don't know if that's more efficient.

Comment: thanks. I'd prefer arrow function because it is ES6 while .bind() is ES5

Answer (score 0):

In your example you could either you arrow functions and make the form as you stated.

The other option is to have a constructor in which you bind.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

then your form would be 
`<form onChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to bind the function to the correct context.

> You are right when you want to make use of functions or attributes
>   that are defined in the context of the React Class then you need to
>   bind your functions.

Another approach to bind the functions is to specify the binding in the constructor

like

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.handleChange = this.handlechange.bind(this);

}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
       val: 'abc'
     }
    
}
handleSubmit(e) {
        console.log(this.state.val)
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(this.state.val)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-4">
                <form onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="user"/>
                    <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="comments"/>
                    <input type="submit" hidden/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This will create new function on every render. It's not recommended (eg. 'reference' of this function is different on every render, so it's harder to know if componentShouldUpdate)

Comment: @pie6k, yes you are right, however this is a quick solution. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753 for detailed answer on how to avoid binding in render