# How to avoid bind or inline arrow functions inside render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions, function-binding, class-fields

We should avoid method binding inside render because during re-rendering it will create the new methods instead of using the old one, that will affect the performance.

So for the scenarios like this:

```
<input onChange = { this._handleChange.bind(this) } ...../>
```

We can bind `_handleChange` method either in constructor:

```
this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
```

Or we can use [property initializer syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/):

```
_handleChange = () => {....}
```

Now lets consider the case where we want to pass some extra parameter, lets say in a simple todo app, onclick of item i need to delete the item from array, for that i need to pass either the item index or the todo name in each onClick method:

```
todos.map(el => <div key={el} onClick={this._deleteTodo.bind(this, el)}> {el} </div>)
```

For now just assume that todo names are unique.

As per [**DOC**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html):

> The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created
>   each time the component renders.

**Question:**

How to avoid this way of binding inside render method or what are the alternatives of this?

Kindly provide any reference or example, thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**First:** A simple solution will be to create a component for the content inside a map function and pass the values as props and when you call the function from the child component you can pass the value to the function passed down as props.

**Parent**

```
deleteTodo = (val) => {
    console.log(val)
}
todos.map(el => 
    <MyComponent val={el} onClick={this.deleteTodo}/> 

)
```

**MyComponent**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    deleteTodo = () => {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.val);
    }
    render() {
       return <div  onClick={this.deleteTodo}> {this.props.val} </div>
    }
}
```

Sample snippet

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
     _deleteTodo = (val) => {
        console.log(val)
    }
    render() {
        var todos = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        return (
           <div>{todos.map(el => 
             <MyComponent key={el} val={el} onClick={this._deleteTodo}/> 
        
           )}</div>
        )
    }
    
   
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
        _deleteTodo = () => {
                     console.log('here');   this.props.onClick(this.props.val);
        }
        render() {
           return <div onClick={this._deleteTodo}> {this.props.val} </div>
        }
    }
    
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

**Second:** The other approach to it would be to use memoize and return a function

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this._deleteTodoListener = _.memoize(
                   this._deleteTodo, (element) => {
                        return element.hashCode();
                    }
              )
}

_deleteTodo = (element) => {
   //delete handling here
}
```

and using it like

```
todos.map(el => <div key={el} onClick={this._deleteTodoListener(el)}> {el} </div>)
```

> P.S. However this is not a best solution and will still result in
>   multiple functions being created but is still an improvement over the
>   initial case.

**Third:** However a more appropriate solution to this will be to add an `attribute` to the topmost div and get the value from `event` like

```
_deleteTodo = (e) => {
     console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-value'));

 }

 todos.map(el => <div key={el} data-value={el} onClick={this._deleteTodo}> {el} </div>)
```

However, in this case the attributes are converted to string using toString method and hence and object will be converted to `[Object Object]` and and array like `["1" , "2", "3"]` as `"1, 2, 3"`

Comment: yes we can do that, but with this we need to create separate components and put the parent child relation, i think this will be not that scalable  since in large application we used to do this kind of binding at multiple places.

Comment: I've struggled with this as well, and my conclusion is that if this recreation of functions is slowing your application down (which... I guess... could happen if you have a large enough data set that re-renders a lot), you should follow this approach for those components. Otherwise, it's not really an issue for perf, and therefore can be ignored safely.

Comment: Yes but that how you can avoid what you want to and scalabilty shouldn't be a problem here

Comment: In your first two code blocks when you create the class property, you use `deleteTodo`, but when you make reference to it you use `_deleteTodo`. Is this a mistake or does the underscore have some special purpose here?

Comment: @kojow7 Thanks for pointing that out, it was a typo caused due to copying and code from the question and adding my own

Comment: Isn't the curried function approach just as bad for performance as using an arrow function? you will create another function on each render.

Comment: Hmm, this works if there is a parent along with a child component but my question is what if there is no child meaning the map function would look something like.....
itemList.map( (item,index) => <span onclick={"how do I pass index to an onClick function here"} /> )

Comment: @akshaykishore, you can use the Third approach in such a case instead of passing the index to onClick

Answer (score 5):

> How to avoid this way of binding inside render method or what are the
>   alternatives of this?

If you care about re-rendering then `shouldComponentUpdate` and `PureComponent` are your friends and they will help you optimize rendering.

You have to extract "Child" component from the "Parent" and pass always the same props and implement `shouldComponentUpdate` or use `PureComponent`. What we want is a case when we remove a child, other children shouldn't be re-rendered.

**Example**

```
import React, { Component, PureComponent } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Product extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { id, name, onDelete } = this.props;

    console.log(`<Product id=${id} /> render()`);
    return (
      <li>
        {id} - {name}
        <button onClick={() => onDelete(id)}>Delete</button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      products: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Bar' },
      ],
    };

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }

  handleDelete(productId) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      products: prevState.products.filter(product => product.id !== productId),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`<App /> render()`);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.products.map(product => (
              <Product 
                key={product.id}
                onDelete={this.handleDelete}
                {...product}
              />
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/99nZGlyZ

**Expected behaviour**

- `<App /> render()`
- `<Product id=1... render()`
- `<Product id=2... render()`

When we remove `<Product id=2 ...` only `<App />` is re-rendered.

- render()

To see those messages in demo, open the dev tools console.

The same technique is used and described in article: [*React is Slow, React is Fast: Optimizing React Apps in Practice*](https://medium.com/dailyjs/react-is-slow-react-is-fast-optimizing-react-apps-in-practice-394176a11fba) by François Zaninotto.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i think using unique key will solve this one *What we want is a case when we remove a child, other children shouldn't be re-rendered* since just i want to render a single div with text. this approach will play a big role when component is large and we want to avoid re-rendering of it.

Comment: Using `key` property doesn't solve this issue, look at: https://codesandbox.io/s/xVZ7pL6E even if you use `key` property, render() of other `<Product />` are also called. The only change between demo and that link is `Product extends Component` instead of `PureComponent`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45053753/2808062 is definitely exhaustive, but I'd say fighting excessive re-renders instead of just re-creating the tiny callback would bring you more performance improvements. That's normally achieved by implementing a proper `shouldComponentUpdate` in the child component.

Even if the props are exactly the same, the following code will still re-render children unless they prevent it in their own `shouldComponentUpdate` (they might inherit it from `PureComponent`):

```
handleChildClick = itemId => {}

render() {
    return this.props.array.map(itemData => <Child onClick={this.handleChildClick} data={itemData})
}
```

Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/92281/.

So, in order to avoid re-renders, the child component has to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` anyway. Now, the only reasonable implementation is completely ignoring `onClick` regardless of whether it has changed:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.array !== nextProps.array;
}
```

Comment: In your proof, you're calling ReactDom.render twice. This would force all the components to render from top to bottom, so I'm not sure how that counts as proof for re-render based on the approach to using onClick. In fact, you seem to suggest what the official docs suggest for avoiding re-render due to event handler wiring is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for checking out my code! Well, although I realise that my advice actually answers a different question, namely how to avoid unnecessary re-renders instead of how to avoid creating excess functions, but that same quoted doc says in the same paragraph that excess functions are hardly a big deal, unlike unnecessary re-renders. Regarding my calling ReactDOM.render twice, I strongly believe it behaves the same way, here's a similar example where I've changed explicit re-rendering to the one which is caused by some parent state update: https://jsfiddle.net/7a9enxsb/1/.

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#example-passing-params-using-data-attributes) encourages to use **data-attributes** and access them from within `evt.target.dataset`:

```
_deleteTodo = (evt) => {
  const elementToDelete = evt.target.dataset.el;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    todos: prevState.todos.filter(el => el !== elementToDelete)
  }))
}

// and from render:

todos.map(
  el => <div key={el} data-el={el} onClick={this._deleteTodo}> {el} </div>
)
```

Also [note](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods) that this makes sense only when you have performance issues:

> **Is it OK to use arrow functions in render methods?**
>
> Generally speaking, yes, it is OK, and it is often the easiest way to
>   pass parameters to callback functions.
>
> If you do have performance issues, by all means, optimize!

Comment: Since your answer is now in 2018, just to share nowadays you can use "React Hook"

Comment: Are you talking about `useCallback`?