# react binding events handler with arrow function

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

How to correct set data about item in callback when i iterate list? I found this solution:

```
handleKeyPress = (item) => (e) => {...}
...
onClick={handleKeyPress(item)}
```

Is it not bast way maybe?

Comment: But, obviously when component re renders happens create a new closure function. Is it not best way maybe? 
I guess better way to put item's id in a data attribute. And find item later, isn't it?

Comment: First of all the above approach shouldn't work since handelKeyPress is being called on every render, secondly you are right every rerender creates a new function, the solution is to create a wrapper around the component and then pass the desired values, See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-inside-render-method

Comment: Thanks, for answer!
Ok, handelKeyPress it's not good example. What about onClick function?
Handler'll be look like:
handler = (e) => {
  const item = list[event.target.dataset.id];
  ...
}

Comment: there are two approched to avoid, `onClick={()=>{this.handleKeyPress(item)}}`, one that I mentioned in the above answer, to create a wrapper component and pass back the props and second to memoize the function like `onClick={this.handleKeyPressLister(item)}` and using it `handleKeyPressListener(item) {
       return this.handleKeyPress.bind(this, item);
}` where handleKeyPressListener is memoized function