# Correct way to pass an argument to parent component callback in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

After writing a quite large application for the first time with react I've come accross an issue where my re-renders are basically freezing the UI which is so bad for the UX.

I did not know that passing an anonymous function as a prop caused the entire receiving component every time. So now I'm trying to fix my functions but find it quite hard to get right.

So currently I have a component called `NavBar` which has subcomponents called `NavBarLink`. Each `NavBarLink` calls the same `showPopup(arg)` function. The argument for `showPopup(arg)` however is based on which `NavBarLink` is clicked.

**Example**

```
render() {
    return (
        <NavBarLink onClick={() => showPopup("UNIQUE_POPUP_ID")}>Link 1</NavBarLink>
        <NavBarLink onClick={() => showPopup("ANOTHER_POPUP_ID")}>Link 2</NavBarLink>
    );
}
```

**Question**

How can I have the same developer experience but don't suffer from the re-rendering issues?

**Related articles**

- [Why Arrow Functions and bind in React’s Render are Problematic](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36)
- [React Pattern: Extract Child Components to Avoid Binding](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-pattern-extract-child-components-to-avoid-binding-e3ad8310725e)
- [React Binding Patterns: 5 Approaches for Handling `this`](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: Perhaps pass in showPopup and the popup id as two separate props, and at the appropriate time have the NavBarLink component call `this.props.showPopup(this.props.popupId)

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753

Answer (score 3):

To stop the function being created on each render, you can define them as class methods, and pass the IDs as props to each `NavBarLink`

```
class MyComponent {
  handleClick = (id) => {
    return showPopup(id)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBarLink onClick={this.handleClick} id='UNIQUE_POPUP_ID'>Link 1</NavBarLink>
        <NavBarLink onClick={this.handleClick} id='ANOTHER_POPUP_ID'>Link 2</NavBarLink>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

then in your `NavBarLink` class, you add another method to call the handler with the ID passed in the props.

```
class NavBarLink {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.id)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <a onClick={this.handleClick}>...</a>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope I interpreted your question correctly!

Comment: Thanks, but this is like 6 lines of code more for a simple argument pass to the onClick function, to me this seems so much boilerplate no?

Comment: I think it's the simplest way of ensuring the callback is only created once, short of using a `memoize` function or similar. To be honest there are probably other places you can optimise your code, unless this is being called like 23957923 times a second