# div's id attribute is undefined/not getting captured onClick in a react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm mapping data from the api response and rendering multiple divs out of it. Along with that I'm assigning a unique id from the response to the id attribute of each div like this:

```
...lists.map(list => {
  return (
  <div className='one' key={list.id} id={list.id} onClick={this.handleClick}>
    <div className='two'>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <span>Foo Bar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
)
})

handleClick = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.id)
  // other stuff
}
```

**The Problem:**

Whenever the outer div (`className='one'`) is clicked the console logs undefined. However, if I assign the id value to the inner div (`className='two'`) it logs the value of id **only if the click is made within the dimensions of the inner div**. Same is the case with the `<span>` and `<p>` tags.

Basically, the onClick returns a different target on clicking different html elements.

**Expected result:**

Clicking the parent div or anywhere inside that div should always return the value of the id attribute of the parent div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing is when you define `onClick` on the `topMost` parent, you need to use `e.currentTarget.id` instead of `e.target.id` since `e.target` will give you the element on which you clicked rather then the parent on which `onClick` listener is defined

```js
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
  lists: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id:3}]
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.lists.map(list => {
          console.log(list.id)
          return (
          <div className='one' key={list.id} id={list.id} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <div className='two'>
              <p>Hello World</p>
              <span>Foo Bar</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
       })
       }
    </div>
  )
}

handleClick = (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.id)
  
  // other stuff
}

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham, just exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Check out this answer too, It could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753

Comment: Went through it all and I think it'll be the best solution for handling this the correct way. Creating a separate component and passing id as props would not only be a cleaner but also an efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the problem isn't Reactjs, the problem is the event target.

You are using `e.target` when you have to use `event.currentTarget`, here is the difference.

- `target` is the element that triggered the event (e.g., the user clicked on)
- `currentTarget` is the element that the event listener is attached to.

Let see this in an example:

```js
let tacos = [{
  person: "John",
  ingredient: 'Guacamole'
 }, {
  person: 'Sally',
  ingredient: 'Beef'
 }];

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>List of tacos:</h3>
        <TacosList tacos={tacos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TacosList extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
 
  handleClick(event) {
   const currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
    
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(currentTarget.id);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.tacos.map((taco, index) => (
     <div className="one" id={`reference-${index}`} key={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>
           <p>{taco.person}: {taco.ingredient}</p>       
     </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.one {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

> Note that you can click on the `div` and `p` element and both will trigger the event, in the case of `p` it will propagate the event up to the `div` , therefore, it's when the event target changes

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor, just put this line:

```
constructor() {
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

After this, you will be able to access the ref to the element,

For more detail please go through this link :
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

try to set event as function param

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.id)
  // other stuff
}
```

Comment: I had that in my code already, only didn't put it in the question.

Answer (score -2):

if you are already using ES6

I would change the code a bit, so it will easier to understand and work with no special glitches with `events` target and attributes

```
lists.map(list => {
    return (
       <div 
           className='one' 
           key={list.id} 
           onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, list.id)

           <div className='two'>
             <p>Hello World</p>
             <span>Foo Bar</span>
           </div>
       </div>
    )
 })

 handleClick = (listId) => {
   console.log(listId)
   // other stuff
 }
```

as you can see here, I just call the method with the list id and I'm done

Comment: anonymous functions causes re-render all the time since it will return a new reference every time this component is rendered

Comment: @JoseAPL now I removed the anonymous function. Dont see a reason to downvote it because of that. But now it wont rerender

Comment: `this.handleClick.bind`  will also cause the same effect cause you are binding a new reference, it has to be an internal function bound once, I do this because this causes performance issues for React projects!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this since bind returns a new function everytime. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753