# Passing a custom argument to the eventListener in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

I have a loop that displays data and when clicking the data it should run a method that gets the clicked item.

ie:

```
items.map(item => {
    return (
        <div
               onClick={someMethod(item)}>
               Some content
                </div>
     );
}
```

The example won’t work properly but it’s just to show the situation.
I know 2 options but both will make the template render each time:

1. Use arrow function

   ```
   onClick={()=>someMethod(item)}
   ```
2. Use bind

   ```
   onClick={someMethod.bind(this, item)}
   ```

Any better ideas that won’t cause rerender?

Comment: I know 2 options but both will make the template render each time: ? does that re render on click ?

Comment: yea explain how do you know it renders 2x

Comment: Didn’t check yet, just trusted another question I read hear from google. If one of those ways are good so that’s great

Comment: This is the Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642018/divs-id-attribute-is-undefined-not-getting-captured-onclick-in-a-react-app/46642251#46642251

Comment: It is difficult to provide an answer to your question until you describe precisely the behavior you see when you run the code yourself rather than the behavior you anticipate will happen from what you read elsewhere.