# How to access name of a button type mui ListItem in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have create a material-ui list, in which each ListItem is a button, but when I try to access the name prop of the button it gives undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginFront from './login/loginFront';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {List, ListItem, ListItemText} from '@material-ui/core';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <List component='nav'>
        <ListItem button name='bName' onClick={event => console.log(event.target.name)} />
        <ListItemText primary='item1' />
      </List>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

`console.log(event.target.name)` gives `undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
onClick={event => console.log(event.target.getAttribute('name'))}
```

Use the `getAttribute` method to get the value of `name`

The `html` you see on the page is just the rendered representation of the DOM. The properties of nodes on the DOM tree don't match up with the attributes on the `html` element.

When creating the standard they wouldn't have wanted the interface for the DOM element be the same as the attribute because you might add an attribute that conflicts with an existing property or method however this is just conjecture.

**EDIT**

`onClick={event => console.log(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('name'))}`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642018/divs-id-attribute-is-undefined-not-getting-captured-onclick-in-a-react-app) for the difference between `target` and `currentTarget`.

> The thing is when you define onClick on the topMost parent, you need to use e.currentTarget.id instead of e.target.id since e.target will give you the element on which you clicked rather then the parent on which onClick listener is defined

Comment: thanks, it worked. I'll accept the answer once ten minutes are up. Can you please elaborate what exactly is going on, why I can't directly access `event.target.name`

Comment: I have to select the another post as answer because in my case `event.target.getAttribute('name')` is not returning the name immediately or so it seems. I am passing the name as a parameter to the callback and it works as expected

Comment: bear in mind the other answer is basically suggesting you do this: `event => console.log('bName')`, which isn't retuning the name, instead it just returns the string you gave it.

Comment: I get the point but your solution most of the times return `undefined`, can you suggest a workaround for that.

Comment: Yeah use this `onClick={event => console.log(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('name'))}`

Comment: yep, this gives the expected behavior, can you please add this to your post so the answer is complete and please explain the reason why `event.target.getAttribute('name')` is undefined most of the times and how it is fixed by  `event.currentTarget.getAttribute('name')`

Comment: It's almost out of the scope of this question to be honest, I'll link another relevant stackoverflow answer though

Answer (score 0):

Material-ui does not have a native way to do it. A simple way to bypass it is to not use `name` at all and pass your parameter in a preset function.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    clickHandler = name => ev => {
        console.log(name)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <List component='nav'>
                <ListItem button onClick={this.clickHandler('bName')} />
                <ListItemText primary='item1' />
            </List>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```