# Getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

I've stated to learn React and don't understand properly how to use `state`. Getting error `TypeError`:

```
Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

And I can't use `setState()` and don't know why. Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong. I've looked at similar problems and they didn't resolve my problem.

Here's code:

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentPage : this.pageTemplates.loginPageTemplate
        };

        this.checkLogIn = this.checkLogIn.bind(this);
    };

    pageTemplates = {
        loginPageTemplate: (
            <div className="loginPage">
                <div id='signIn'>
                    <div className='loginPageError'/>
                    <input placeholder="Enter your username" id="loginName" type="text"/>
                    <input placeholder="Enter your password" id="loginPass" type="password"/>
                    <input value="SIGN IN" id="logIn" onClick={this.checkLogIn} type="button"/>
                </div>
            </div>),
        mainPageTemplate: (
            <div id='MainPage'>
                <div className='mainSidebar'>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    };

    render() {
        return this.state.currentPage;
    };

    checkLogIn() {
            this.setState({currentPage : this.pageTemplates.mainPageTemplate});
    }

}
```

Comment: Why `this.pageTemplates.loginPageTemplate` in the state anyway? You need to store current page state like `login` or `main`, i suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `onClick` attribute of `input` element and bind `this` as you are referring to `this.setState` in your `checkLogIn` event handler. Edit your `onClick` attribute as below;

```
<input value="SIGN IN" id="logIn" onClick={this.checkLogIn.bind(this)} type="button"/>
```

---

**Edit for clarification:** Your binding in constructor is perfectly fine, but it is not affecting and binding `this.state.currentPage` right now which is being `return` inside the `render()` method as;

```
render() {
    return this.state.currentPage;
};
```

However, if you had rendered `this.pageTemplates.loginPageTemplate` directly as an element

```
render() {
    return (<div className="loginPage"> ... </div>);
};
```

inside `render()` method, it would work well without changing `onClick` attribute of `input` element. So, the code below, will be a clear example to understand it better.

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentPage : "loginPage"
        };

        this.checkLogIn = this.checkLogIn.bind(this);

    };

    render() {
        // output is "loginPage" in first run
        // then becomes "mainSidebar" when button clicked
        console.log(this.state.currentPage);

        return (
            <div className="loginPage">
                <div id='signIn'>
                    <div className='loginPageError'/>
                    <input placeholder="Enter your username" id="loginName" type="text"/>
                    <input placeholder="Enter your password" id="loginPass" type="password"/>
                    <input value="SIGN IN" id="logIn" onClick={this.checkLogIn} type="button"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    checkLogIn() {
            this.setState({currentPage : "mainSidebar"});
    }

}
```

Comment: But why does not working binding that i wrote at constructor?

Comment: binding inside render method isn't a good approach, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753

Comment: Right now, you are rendering `loginPageTemplate` as a state variable in your `render()` method with  `return this.state.currentPage`. While doing that, the `input` element that has  `onClick={this.checkLogIn}` attribute is not being affected by `this.checkLogIn = this.checkLogIn.bind(this)` binding in your constructor. That is why when you click the button, `this` is undefined. So try to change your code and render `loginPageTemplate` directly in your `render()` as `render() { <div className="loginPage"> ... </div> };`  You will get it.

Comment: @KURWAMAN updated the answer and added another example for clarification. Hope it helps.

Comment: @KartalErkoç Thanks for explanation, now i understood.

Answer (score 1):

or use the following:

```
onClick={() => this.checkLogIn()}
```

working example:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/97603/
```