# Best practice in React regarding the context `this`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, this, arrow-functions

Which of the following is the best practice with regard to performance in a React class component:

1. Binding a call back function in the constructor:

   ```
   constructor(props)
   {
       /* some code */
       this.onChange= this.onChange.bind(this)
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>
             <input onChange={this.onChange}
         </div>
      );
   }

   onChange(event) {
   /* some code involving 'this' */
   }
   ```
2. Using an arrow function instead of a normal function:

   ```
   constructor(props)
   {
       /* some code */
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>
             <input onChange={this.onChange}
         </div>
      );
   }

   onChange = (event) => {
   /* some code involving 'this' */
   }
   ```
3. Sticking to a normal function but declaring an arrow function in the onChange field:

   ```
   constructor(props)
   {
       /* some code */
   }

   render() {
   <div>
       <input onChange={(event) => {this.onChange(event)}}
   </div>
   }

   onChange(event) {
   /* some code involving 'this' */
   }
   ```

Thanks!

Comment: Numbers 2 and 3 might not work the way you'd expect; arrow functions don't bind their own `this`. I'd go with 1.

Comment: @castis "arrow functions don't bind their own this" That's why 2 and 3 will work exactly as expected :)

Comment: The third method is not a good idea, as it creates a new function everytime render is called, you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753 also , The first and third method are equivalent

Comment: FYI, in #3, the constructor initialization is unnecessary because `this.onChange(event)` within the handler causes the calling context to be set correctly anyway.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to delete it after copy-pasting from option 1 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All 3 options, with regards to `this`, behave the same.

Option 3 is creating a new function on every render and is thus less desired than options 1 and 2 (since such re-creation is unnecessary and could potentially hinder performance)

As far as options 1 and 2, they come down to the same behavior with slight differences unrelated to the behavior of `this`.

The trick to understanding why they behave the same with `this` is to know what the following code does:

```
method = () => {}
```

It's just syntactic sugar to add a method to an instance:

```
class A {
  method = () => {}
}

// is the same as

class A {
  constructor() {
    this.method = () => {}
  }
}
```

See how [Babel transpiles it](http://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oFsCmAXAFgewBNoBeaACgEoSA-RAXyTqA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2016%2Creact%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=Node-7.4&version=6.26.0&envVersion=).

Since an arrow function [inherits the context it is defined in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as `this`, the context for option 2 is the class itself.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.method = () => {
      return this;
      //     ^^^^ this points to the instance of A
    }
  }
}

const a = new A();
console.log(a.method() === a); // true
```

Which is the same thing for option 1:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.method = this.method.bind(this);
  }
  method() {
    return this;
    //     ^^^^ this points to the instance of A
  }
}

const a = new A();
console.log(a.method() === a); // true
```

That means your options come down to the difference between:

```
// option 1
constructor(props) {
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
}

onChange() {
 // code for onChange...
}
```

and

```
// option 2
constructor(props) {
  this.onChange = () => /* code for onChange */
}
```

The main advantage I would give to option 1 is that it has a named function instead of an arrow function, which makes debugging a bit easier when examining stack traces (although [function name inferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names) dilutes this point a bit).

The main advantage I would give to option 2 is that it's a bit "cleaner" looking, as in less verbose, code but that is a subjective opinion.

Overall, option 1 and option 2 are practically indifferent.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer!! So option 1 and option 2 are the same performance wise?

Comment: Yes, in the practical sense. Meaning their perf differences are minimal. Option 1 does have an extra function on the prototype that gets put on every instance when instantiating it but that's just one extra function and shouldn't be an issue.