# Should we avoid arrow function inside JSX: ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Is providing a setState-function as onClick-property directly a bad thing, cause the function will be defined with every render again? Should it be declared as function instead, e. g. this.open?

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen })}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's fine to use inline setState, though you may want to use the `prevState` syntax shown [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Nothing wrong with above code.

Comment: As long as you write Arrow function in render it will be called multiple times.  Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cause the function will be defined with every render again?

Yes, btw it doesn't matter whether you are using block body or concise body of **[arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)**, each time a new function will get created. You should try to avoid [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) inside JSX.

If you bind the method in the constructor then it will get created only once, and for each re-rendering same reference will be used.

```
Block Body:  () => {....}

Concise Body: () => expression
```

> Should it be declared as function instead?

As mentioned in the **[Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)**:

In most of the cases its fine, but we generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.

Write it like this:

```
handleClick(){
   this.setState(prevState => ({ isOpen: !prevState.isOpen }))
}

onClick={this.handleClick}
```