# multi select reactjs handlechange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 select like this

```
    const { selectedOption , selectedOption2, selectedOption3} = this.state;
    const value = selectedOption && selectedOption.value;
    const value2 = selectedOption2 && selectedOption2.value;
    const value3 = selectedOption3 && selectedOption3.value;
    <Select
       name="form-field-name1"
       value={value}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       options={[
           { value: 'Ados et jeunes', label: 'One' },
           { value: 'Pêche à la truite', label: 'Two' },
              ]}
          />
     <Select
      name="form-field-name2"
      value={value2}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      options={[
       { value: 'XXXX', label: 'OneX' },
       { value: 'XXXXXX', label: 'TwoX' },
     ]}
    />
   <Select
     name="form-field-name3"
     value={value3}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     options={[
      { value: 'rrrrrr', label: 'Oner' },
      { value: 'rrrrrrrr', label: 'Twor' },
      ]}
   />
```

and when i don't know how to change the value with handlechange

```
handleChange(selectedOption) {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Selected: ${selectedOption.label}`);
  }
```

how can i update selectoption 2 and 3 in the same function

Comment: Are you sure your `selectedOption`  argument is being passed correctly? What is the output of your log... We need more clear info.

Answer (score 2):

In your handleChange function, you need to send the id of the select field whose value changes like `onChange={(selectedOption) => this.handleChange(selectedOption, 'selectedOption2')}`

```
   <Select
       name="form-field-name1"
       value={value}
       onChange={(selectedOption) => this.handleChange(selectedOption, 'selectedOption')}
       options={[
           { value: 'Ados et jeunes', label: 'One' },
           { value: 'Pêche à la truite', label: 'Two' },
              ]}
          />
     <Select
      name="form-field-name2"
      value={value2}
      onChange={(selectedOption) => this.handleChange(selectedOption, 'selectedOption2')}
      options={[
       { value: 'XXXX', label: 'OneX' },
       { value: 'XXXXXX', label: 'TwoX' },
     ]}
    />
   <Select
     name="form-field-name3"
     value={value3}
     onChange={(selectedOption) => this.handleChange(selectedOption, 'selectedOption3')}
     options={[
      { value: 'rrrrrr', label: 'Oner' },
      { value: 'rrrrrrrr', label: 'Twor' },
      ]}
   />
```

and then you can have the handleChange function like

```
handleChange(selectedOption, key) {
    this.setState({ [key]: selectedOption });
}
```

You can also have a look at [`How to avoid binding in render method`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753) to achieve the same result without using arrow function

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this is the best way for doing this, but for the size of the form it should still be easy enough to follow.

```
handleChange = (event) =>{
    switch(event.target.id){
        case 'select1':
            // Your code for specific select
            break;
        case 'select2':
            // Your code for specific select
            break;
        case 'select3':
            // Your code for specific select
            break;
    }
}
```

Then in each of the selects just add an id tag for 'select1', '...2','...3'