# Show data on buttonclick

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react ,Trying to build a app . The basic functionality i am trying to implement is 
I will have some text ,with a button called **show details** ,clicking the button will show details regarding the text .

I have the text as well as the details saved as a object array in state

```
Watcher_list :[
  {
    id:uuid.v4(),
    name : "Memory",
    showdetails : "False"
  },
  {
    id:uuid.v4(),
    name  :"Network",
    showdetails : "False"
  }
]
```

for the component to render the page the code is as follows

```
class Watchers extends Component 
{
    showdetails(id)
    {
        this.props.showonclick(id);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.item.showdetails ==="True") {

            return (
                <div className="Watchers" >
                    <li>{this.props.item.name}</li>
                    <p1>{this.props.item.id} </p1>
                    <button ref="show details" onClick={this.showdetails.bind(this,this.props.item.id)} > 
                        Show Details 
                    </button>
                </div>
             );}
        else {
            return (
                <div className="Watchers" >
                    <li>{this.props.item.name}</li>
                    <button ref="show details" onClick={this.showdetails.bind(this,this.props.item.id)} > 
                        Show Details 
                    </button>
                </div>
            );
        }  
    }
}

export default Watchers;
```

the handler for show click just updates the value of showdetails in the state ,ad upon re rendering the details are displayed.

I just wanted to know wether this is the best way to do this ,or is there a much smarter way that I can do the same thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can improve on,

**First:** you have a lot of redundant code that can be avoided by using conditional rendering like

```
class Watchers extends Component {
   showdetails(id){
        this.props.showonclick(id);
   }
   render() {
     return (
       <div className="Watchers" >
         <li>{this.props.item.name}</li>
         {this.props.item.showdetails ==="True" ? <p1>{this.props.item.id} </p1> : null }
        <button ref={(ref) => this.showDetails = ref} onClick =
    {this.showdetails.bind(this,this.props.item.id)} > Show Details </button>
    </div>
    );
   } 
}

export default Watchers;
```

**Second:** bind inside render is not a good pattern since it creates a new function everytime render is called. Check [this answer on how to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753).

**Third:** I don't see any point on why you are using ref looking at the code in your question, but even if you need it, you need to use `ref callback` like `ref={(ref) => this.showDetails = ref}` instead of `string refs` since [`string refs are a legacy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)

Comment: Thanks alot ,this answered most of my doubts ,I basically wanted to know if I was on the right track, and your answer explains it pretty well . I am still not able to understand the ref callback ,ill use the link provided to read up on it . Thanks

Comment: Yeah, react refs are currently defined using a callback function, the react documentation has a pretty decent explanation on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

1. [You need not bind inside render function](https://ryanfunduk.com/articles/never-bind-in-render/).
2. No need to set ref
3. For a change in ID, you do not require separate conditions. You can use the short circuit operator.

   ```
    class Watchers extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.showdetails = this.showdetails.bind(this);
    }
    showdetails(id) {
      this.props.showonclick(id);
    }
    render() {
      return ( 
       <div className = "Watchers">
        <li> {this.props.item.name}</li> 
        {
          this.props.item.showdetails === "True" &&
          <p> {this.props.item.id} < /p>
        } 
        <button onClick = {this.showdetails}>Show Details</button> 
      </div>
   );
   }
   }

   export default Watchers;
   ```

If you are setting state locally, you should probably set `showDetails` to Boolean true instead of a String like you have provided.

Comment: Thanks much ,this answer helped clear most of the things that  were unclear to me .