# react native - binding functions not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using this library: https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable to create an interactable view.

Here's an example of a working use case:

```
import { Component }, React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Interactable from 'react-native-interactable';


class MainScreen extends Component {

  onDrag() {
    console.log("dragging...")
  }

  onSnap() {
    console.log("snapped!")
  }

  render() {
      return(
          <View>
              <Interactable.View
                  style={{backgroundColor: '#000000', width: 100, height: 100}}
                  horizontalOnly={true}
                  snapPoints={[{x: 0}, {x: 200}]}
                  onDrag={ () => this.onDrag() }
                  onSnap={ () => this.onSnap() }>

              </Interactable.View>
          </View>
      )
  }

}
```

However, because I wanted to get the event object in the call (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable/blob/master/PROPS.md#ondrag-function)), I'm unable to implement it correctly. For some reason, the onDrag and onSnap functions aren't getting called. Here's my implementation of binding functions (that isn't working correctly):

```
import { Component }, React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Interactable from 'react-native-interactable';


class MainScreen extends Component {

  onDrag(event) {
    console.log("dragging...", event)
  }

  onSnap(event) {
    console.log("snapped!", event)
  }

  render() {
      return(
          <View>
              <Interactable.View
                  style={{backgroundColor: '#000000', width: 100, height: 100}}
                  horizontalOnly={true}
                  snapPoints={[{x: 0}, {x: 200}]}
                  onDrag={ this.onDrag.bind(this) }
                  onSnap={ this.onSnap.bind(this) }>

              </Interactable.View>
          </View>
      )
  }

}
```

Anyone has any idea what am I missing out on? I also tried binding the functions within the constructor, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event object to the arrow function while binding like

```
  <View>
          <Interactable.View
              style={{backgroundColor: '#000000', width: 100, height: 100}}
              horizontalOnly={true}
              snapPoints={[{x: 0}, {x: 200}]}
              onDrag={ (e) => this.onDrag(e) }
              onSnap={ (e) => this.onSnap(e) }>

          </Interactable.View>
      </View>
```

However its not a good idea to bind functions in render method as a new instance of it is created everytime render is called. Check this question for more details:

[How to avoid binding in render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753)

You could instead bind the function in constructor for your use case

```
class MainScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.onDrag = this.onDrag.bind(this);
     this.onSnap = this.onSnap.bind(this);
  }
  onDrag(event) {
    console.log("dragging...", event)
  }

  onSnap(event) {
    console.log("snapped!", event)
  }

  render() {
      return(
          <View>
              <Interactable.View
                  style={{backgroundColor: '#000000', width: 100, height: 100}}
                  horizontalOnly={true}
                  snapPoints={[{x: 0}, {x: 200}]}
                  onDrag={ this.onDrag }
                  onSnap={ this.onSnap }>

              </Interactable.View>
          </View>
      )
  }

}
```

Comment: I've already tried this. I did mention this above: `I also tried binding the functions within the constructor, but it didn't seem to work.`. Tried it again, it's still not working.

Comment: is the event object null or the function is not called at all

Comment: The function is not getting called at all.

Comment: can you produce a reproducible demo of codesandbox or something

Comment: I just checked again. When I print simple text like `console.log("testing");`, it's showing it in logs, but right when `console.log("event", event);` is executed code-wise, everything in the app stops functioning. Even the `testing` doesn't show in logs when I try to drag the component again. I think the app is crashing or something but it shows no error. Everything just hangs by itself. P.S. the bound function is getting called, but on printing `event` in console, everything stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the reason it wasn't working was because printing `console.log("dragging...", event);` caused an error leading the app to crash and stop working.

The easy fix was to not print the object event directly. When I tried to print `event.nativeEvent.state`, the code was working. Though, this was the only error, I'm not sure why React Native debugger didn't pop up the error OR print the error in the logger.