# Unable to use ref to call the child method on a connect redux component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, parent-child, ref

I want to call `SingleCard` child component methods  in `renderHiddenItem`. I have assigned different **ref** name for each `renderItem`. But when I call **this.name**, it is `undefined`. Anything is wrong in this code?  How can I achieve this?

```
    <SwipeListView
        data={this.state.listViewData}
        renderItem={(data, i) => {
          const name = 'childRef'+i
          return (
            <SingleCard
              ref={component => this.name = component}
              itm={data.item}
            />
          );
        }}
        renderHiddenItem={(data, i) => {
            const name = 'childRef'+i
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => console.log(this.name)}>
                  <Text> h </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }
        }}
      />
```

**Update:**
I want to trigger some action which is written in the singleCard component. Need to call that in `renderHiddenItem`.

Like this:

```
this.childRef0.someMethod
this.childRef1.someMethod
```

Comment: Looks to me like renderHiddenItem gets called either while or before the SingleCard component has mounted which means the ref will always be undefined. Can you elaborate on what you want to do? Maybe there's another solution.

Comment: @NemiShah Updated! renderHiddenItem is called after renderItem.

Comment: Yes but does the SingleCard component mount before renderHiddenItem? Try logging in the componentDidMount for the single card

Comment: No. renderHiddenItem is called before componentDidMount from the single card.

Comment: @NemiShah Doc says - The ref is first set after the first `render`, but before `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of name you need to use the dynamic variable which can be done by using the bracket notation

```
<SwipeListView
    data={this.state.listViewData}
    renderItem={(data, i) => {
      const name = 'childRef'+i
      return (
        <SingleCard
          ref={component => this[name] = component}
          itm={data.item}
        />
      );
    }}
    renderHiddenItem={(data, i) => {
        const name = 'childRef'+i
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => console.log(this[name])}>
              <Text> h </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }
    }}
  />
```

Also when you use `ref` on a component which is created using an HOC for instance `connect` from `react-redux`, most of the libraries provide a method called `getWrappedInstance` to get the ref for the actual component instead of the `connect` component. You can use it like

```
this[name].getWrappedInstance()
```

but initially you need to set `{withRef: true}` as the fourth parameter to `connect` being used in `SingleCard` like

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(SingleCard);
```

You can read more about it here

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: It is printed `connect` object which does have any child component methods and `refs` key has empty object.

Comment: Is SingleCard created using an HOC or is it a connect component from redux

Comment: No TouchableOpacity not an HOC.

Comment: No, not TouchableOpacity, I was asking about SingleCard on .which you apply a ref

Comment: ya. singleCard is a connect component from redux.

Comment: Awesome. You **killed** it !!! One last thing,  can we write `ref={component => this[name] = component}` bind func inside render?

Comment: @Balasubramanian, its not advised to use arrow functions in render . you might check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753.

Comment: Let me know if you still face trouble with this

Comment: Thanks a lot! Moved bind func away from render. Its working smoothly now.

Comment: Glad it helped you. :)

Comment: Consider upvoting the answer to avoid binding in render if it helped