# Optimization of arrow functions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Apart from needing to create a new function each time `render` is invoked, are there any other differences from using:

```
class {
   on = () => true
   render = () => <z on={this.on} />
}
```

vs

```
class {
   render = () => <z on={() => true} />
}
```

For example, are there any optimizations that browsers make? Are there any implementation differences?

If there are zero differences, would it make sense for something like bable to transform the code to avoid creating the function in the `render` function?

Comment: `{} => true` si not valid. And what is the purpose of having a function that always returns true ?

Comment: As always: yes the second *might* be faster if optimizations in js would be logical. And even then: Why do you care? Are you having performance problems? If so, its definetly not the arrow func

Comment: @klugjo thanks have corrected, purpose is not what’s in the function, rather how the function is defined.

Comment: @JonasW. Why do I care: simply curiosity

Comment: AFAIK, ```render = () => {}``` won't work, will it? Like a half year ago I tried it and it generated an error in babel

Comment: I guess I’m asking what’s the difference between these two except for one is creating a new function https://codesandbox.io/s/7jo85xpx2x

Comment: @FabianCook, there isn't any difference between the two apart from the fact that a new function is created on every render, You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753 is you are looking for ways to avoid arrow function in render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Reactjs point of view, since the arrow function creates a new function everytime, it could potentially cause two performance related problems:

- Could invoke the garbage collector more frequently than usual
- Will cause unnecessary re-render of your components(even the pure components) as new function will be considered as a new prop.

There is already a babel plugin that solves this re-render problem caused by using arrow fn:
[reflective-bind](https://github.com/flexport/reflective-bind)
The performance benefit from using this plugin has been described [here](https://flexport.engineering/ending-the-debate-on-inline-functions-in-react-8c03fabd144)

Comment: I didn’t even think of that point, wouldn’t it cause large performance issues if this is happening?

Comment: Well that depends on many factors like how many arrow fn you are passing as props, how many levels of component nesting to which these arrow fns are passed as props etc

Comment: @FabianCook Do let me know if you have any more questions. If the answer helped you, please accept it so that it will help others in the future.