# Get a reference to clicked item with MaterialUI and React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this simple code in a react component:

```
render(){
    return(
        <List>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.onItemClick} key={1}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.onItemClick} key={2}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.onItemClick} key={3}>Menu item 3</MenuItem>
        </List>
    )
}

onItemClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event, event.target, event.target.key); //???
}
```

When I click on a list item, I want to retrieve its reference to assign the `selected` property of that item. 
The `event.target` gives a `<li>` object instead of a `<MenuItem>` object, so `event.target.key` returns `undefined`

The [material-ui docs](https://material-ui-next.com) don't give any explanation on how to handle events unfortunately.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using `MenuItem` instead of `ListItem` to get the `selected` property. See [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8667)

Comment: Its defined in the doc ! If you want to see examples, you need to go in `Demo` section. See following link : https://material-ui-next.com/demos/menus/

Comment: Thanks Sam, I missed that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the clicked Item, you can either use arrow function or bind in render which isn't the most correct approach

```
<MenuItem onClick={() => this.onItemClick(1)} key={1}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
```

or write a wrapper around MenuItemClick like

```
class ExtendedMenuItem extends React.Component {
   onClick=() => {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.id);
   }
   render(){
      const {id, children, ...others} = this.props;
      return <MenuItem onClick={this.onClick} key={id} {...others}>children</MenuItem>
   }
}
```

and then use it like

```
<ExtendedMenuItem onClick={this.onItemClick} id={1}>Menu item 1</ExtendedMenuItem >
```

Comment: Indeed, this works. Thx! But does this mean that - to use a correct approach - I should always use the wrapper method? Why is the arrow function approach wrong?

Comment: Using arrow function create a new function on every render, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-in-render-method/45053753#45053753

Comment: That makes sense indeed. So my conclusion would be to only use the wrapper solution in case of heavily updated components. Maybe the guys of material-ui should add some built in event handlers in components like `<List>` and `<Menu>` which takes care of these wrappers

Answer (score 1):

`event.target` gives a `li` element because the browser works with the DOM, not the virtual structure that React keeps in memory.

There is no `MenuItem` element on the rendered page. Instead, there's *the elements that are rendered* by `MenuItem`s.

Click events come from actual DOM elements like div, input, li. Why not from MenuItem? Because there's no `<MenuItem>` on the page. When you click on the elements, you click on `<li>`s, not `<MenuItem>`s.

What you want to do is achievable by setting an "imaginary" click handler on the *virtual* `<MenuItem>`:

```js
<VirtualElement onClick={virtualClickHandler} />
```

Then, when rendering the *real DOM element* `<li>`, the VirtualElement will set on it a *real* click handler:

```js
class VirtualElement {
    realClickHandler (e) { // Let's assume you've bound this in the constructor
        // do stuff with "e" and "this.props"
    }
    render () {
        return <li onClick={realClickHandler} />
    }
}
```

Now, `realClickHandler`'s scope contains `this` and `e`. This means, it can read both the state & (virtual) props of the VirtualElements *and* the *event* object.

The final part - the only thing left is the `virtualClickHandler`. Where does it reside? In `this.props`. Because when earlier you said `<VirtualElement onClick={virtualClickHandler} />`, this onClick handler gets written on the `props` object of the VirtualElement.

What you want to do is call the *virtualClickHandler* from the *realClickHandler*, which sees both the *event* and the *this* object:

```js
realClickHandler (e) {
    // Here you can tell the virtualClickHandler whatever it needs to know:
    this.props.onClick({
        event: e,
        key: this.props.key
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx for this explanation. I use to use another UI library which had event handlers built in. Material-ui doesn't, so that was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that :

```
render(){
    return(
        <List>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.onItemClick(1)} key={1}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.onItemClick(2)} key={2}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.onItemClick(3)} key={3}>Menu item 3</MenuItem>
        </List>
    )
}

onItemClick = itemId=>(event) => {
    console.log(itemId,event, event.target, event.target.key); //???
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is not correct since the `onItemClick` function will be executed during rendering. Instead, `() => this.onItemClick(1)` does work (like Khatri mentioned)