# Facing issues with passing parameters to method in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a demo application from the course.
I have defined my component in following way.

```
const Book = (props) => {
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>");
  console.log(props.onAnswerSelected);
  return (
    <div className="answer" onClick={props.onAnswerSelected}>
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This component renders the book name. On clicking the book name it should pass the book title to the method `onAnswerSelected`. Book is composed inside another component Turn.

```
export default class Turn extends Component {

  render() {

    console.log("Turn props >>> ", this.props);
    return (
      <div className="row turn" style={{backgroundColor: this.highlightTheBackgroundColor(this.props.highlightmapping)}}>
        <div className="col-4 offset-1">
            <img src={this.props.author.imageUrl} className="authorimage" alt="Author"></img>
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">
          {this.props.books.map((title) => <Book title={title} key={title} onAnswerSelected={this.props.onAnswerSelected}></Book>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  highlightTheBackgroundColor(highlightmapping) {
    if(!highlightmapping) {
      highlightmapping = 'none';
    }
    let colors = {
      'none' : "none", 
      'correct' : "green",
      'wrong' : "orange"
    }
    console.log("Input mapping .>>> ", highlightmapping);
    console.log("Required highlight color >> ", colors[highlightmapping]);
    return colors[highlightmapping];
  }
}
```

This is used inside another component called AuthorQuiz.

```
    class AuthorQuiz extends Component {
      render() {
        console.log("TURN DATA FOUND >>> ", this.props.turnData);

        return (
          <div className="container-fluid">

            <Hero />
            <Turn {...this.props.turnData} highlightmapping={this.props.highlightmapping} onAnswerSelected={this.props.onAnswerSelected}/>
            <Continue /> 
            <Footer />

            <PreventDefaultComponent />

            {/* <Button label="Click me!"/>
            <ButtonExntended label="Click Another"/>
            <ClickCounterComponentWithState></ClickCounterComponentWithState> */}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

The function is defined in index.js file which is as follows:


const state = {
    turnData:  getTurnData(Authors),
    allBooks: getAllBooks(Authors),
    highlight: 'none'
}

function getAllBooks(Authors) {
    const allBooks = Authors.reduce(function (p,c, i) {
        return p.concat(c.books);
    }, []);
    return allBooks;
}

function getTurnData(Authors) {
    let allBooks = getAllBooks(Authors);
    console.log("all Books >>>> ", allBooks);
    const fourRandomBooks = shuffle(allBooks).slice(0,4);
    const answer = sample(fourRandomBooks);

    return {books: fourRandomBooks,
        author: Authors.find((author) => author.books.some((title) => title === answer))
    };
}

function onAnswerSelected(event, answer) {
    console.log("On Answer Selected called ... ", answer);
    console.log("Logging the event >>> ", event.target.text);
    const isCorrect = state.allBooks.some((book) => {
        return book === answer;
    });
    state.highlight = isCorrect? "correct" : "wrong";
    // render();
}

// function render() {
    ReactDOM.render(<AuthorQuiz {...state} onAnswerSelected={onAnswerSelected}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
// }

// render();

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

for the sake of shortening the question I have omitted the imports. All I get is in the method is event only, I can't find the answer in it.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If someone can help. Thanks.

P.S I have refered to other questions from there I got the idea of passing an event but when I do event.target.dataset/text/value I get undefined, I think there has to be a react way or better way to pass the value in it.

**Update : 1** This part doesn't work, I get entire h4 or div (depending on where I click in the console). further more when I try to pass the value it still doesn't give out the value in the function, all i get is events inside the function.

the output of on click is as follows:

```
index.js:35 On Answer Selected called ...  <h4>​Roughing it​</h4>​
index.js:35 On Answer Selected called ...  <div class=​"answer" title=​"Roughing it" value=​"Roughing it">​…​</div>​<h4>​Roughing it​</h4>​</div>​
```

Comment: I think you are looking for pass params to any function which is passing as props to any component. so you can try this:

<AuthorQuiz {...state} onAnswerSelected={onAnswerSelected.bind(this, anyParams)}

or 

<AuthorQuiz {...state} onAnswerSelected={this.onAnswerSelected.bind(this, anyNumberOfParams)}

Which will call same component function.

Comment: I have updated the question with newer issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your example, you have passed the book title to the onAnswerSelected function. You can pass it from the `Books` component like

```
const Book = (props) => {
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>");
  console.log(props.onAnswerSelected);
  return (
    <div className="answer" onClick={(e) => props.onAnswerSelected(e, props.title)}>
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and using it in `onAnswerSelected` method from `answer` argument value

Also the reason that `event.target.text/dataset/value` return undefined is because you haven't set those attributes on the `div` element in `Book` and also because they aren't the defined attributes on div and hence you need to access them using `getAttribute` once you define them and using it from the `currentTarget` since it has the handler defined.

Another possible solution is

```
const Book = (props) => {
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>");
  console.log(props.onAnswerSelected);
  return (
    <div className="answer" text={props.title} onClick={props.onAnswerSelected}>
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
    </div>
  )
}

function onAnswerSelected(event) {
    console.log("On Answer Selected called ... ", answer);
    console.log("Logging the event >>> ", event.currentTarget.getAttribute('text'));
    const answer = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('text')
    const isCorrect = state.allBooks.some((book) => {
        return book === answer;
    });
    state.highlight = isCorrect? "correct" : "wrong";
    // render();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering I don't want to use the inline function as it generates multiple unnecessary render calls. And I also don't want to do the getAttribute() thing, what other improvements/changes I need to do to solve the problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use getAttribute. Its usage is perfectly fine. However , you can use the `title` attribute which is a defined attribute in div along with `id` and with these you won't require getAttribute

Comment: Check this answer on how to avoid inline arrow functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting different behaviour, I have updated my question.

Comment: If you read my answer carefully, you would notice that I have used currentTarget instead of `event.target` , currentTarget gives the element on which the handler is defined and not the element clicked

Comment: Thanks, is it perfectly fine to do so? I am new to react and hence I am asking, if you could guide me to react best practices or some online links ? It would be very helpful. is it a good practice to define the methods within class where the element is defined? As @Fawzi mentioned

Comment: Fawzi has converted Book into a class component to define method in it, if you follow the link that I shared in my above comment, you will see that as one approach. However, converting a functional component to a class component just to avoid arrow function is render is more overhead then using the arrow functions inline. React has now proposed a way(Hooks) to use state and lifecycle functionalities in functional components to avoid classes. I would say React docs are the best place to start with React. They suggest all the best practices along with the donts

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the function with the data you need in the parents.

```
{()=>{ props.onAnswerSelected(props.title//or id)}}
```

if you don't want to use the inline function try this

```js
class Book extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onAnswerSelected(this.props.title);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="answer" onClick={this.handleClick}>
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this will then re-render only when the props change (because the handler reference now never changes):

Comment: I don't want to use the inline function as it generates multiple renders.

Comment: I haven't defined my handleClick in the same component, I am not sure whether this will impact it or not but it is still not working all I get is <h4> tag or a <div> tag that depends on where I click.

Comment: you need to define it in the same component so that you can send the parameter.