# binding this and sending to handler

Tags: reactjs, constructor, bind

I know I can bind `this` in a couple of different ways in react like these:

```
<button onClick={this.onSelect.bind(this, data)}>Button</button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={() => this.onSelect(data)}>Button</button>
```

or

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.onSelect= this.onSelect.bind(this)
}
<button onClick={this.onSelect}>Button</button>
```

The problem is that I cannot send data using third option. Is there anyway to use the third option and send data as well?

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-bind-or-inline-arrow-functions-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
  }

  onSelect(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <button onClick={event => this.onSelect(event)}>Button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can use ES6 Arrow Function to send data here, it is called anonymous function calling:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.onSelect= this.onSelect.bind(this)
}
<button onClick={(event) => this.onSelect(event)}>Button</button>
```

Like this.

Answer (score 0):

With the new arrow function brought by the ES6 syntax, you can forget about `bind`.
An arrow function will automatically bind to it's class context. Making your `onSelect` an arrow function will solve your problem.

To send your data, you can preconfigure your function to receive 2 sets of parameters, the first one being your data, and the second being the click event :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { msg: '' }
  }

  onSelect = msg => event => {
    this.setState({ msg })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { msg } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>{msg ? 'Yay, data : ' + msg : 'Click it !'}</h3>
        <button onClick={this.onSelect('I sent data !')}>Button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```