# ReactJS: How does bind work in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building an eCommerce website with an Add To Cart feature, I'm working within the Cart class. I'm using Redux -- the onDelete function is used for when there's a Delete button and I can remove a book from the current cart state by clicking it (calling onClick).

This is what I've been trying but it does not work and throws the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined".

You can see that I've passed *this* to the onClick function in the constructor so in the onClick property of the Button, I have simply passed the cartID into the onClick function:

**Cart.js file**

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onClick = this.onDelete.bind(this);
    }

    onDelete(_id) {
    //
    }

    render() {
        // if more than 1 item in cart array, then render the cart
        // otherwise, render empty
        if(this.props.cart[0]) {
            return this.renderCart();
        } else {
            return this.renderEmpty();
        }       
    }

    renderEmpty() {
        return (<div>Empty Cart</div>)
    }

    renderCart() {
        
        const cartItemsList = this.props.cart.map(function(cartArr) {
            return (
                <Card key={cartArr._id}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <h6>{cartArr.title}</h6>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <h6>USD {cartArr.price}</h6>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <h6>qty. goes here</h6>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <ButtonGroup style={{minWidth:'300px'}}>
                                <Button
                                    variant = "default"
                                    size    = "small">
                                    -
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    variant = "default"
                                    size    = "small">
                                    +
                                </Button>
                                <span>     </span>
                                <Button
                                    onClick = {this.onClick(cartArr._id)}
                                    variant = "danger"
                                    size    = "small">
                                    DELETE
                                </Button>
                            </ButtonGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Card>
            )
        })

        return (
            <Card>
                {cartItemsList}
            </Card>
        )
    }
}
```

I know that a part of this is due to the nature of the this keyword that I am passing to the onClick function. It works fine when I follow a tutorial and add the this keyword at the end of the cartItemList:

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onClick = this.onDelete.bind(this);
    }

    onDelete(_id) {
    //
    }

    render() {
        // if more than 1 item in cart array, then render the cart
        // otherwise, render empty
        if(this.props.cart[0]) {
            return this.renderCart();
        } else {
            return this.renderEmpty();
        }       
    }

    renderEmpty() {
        return (<div>Empty Cart</div>)
    }

    renderCart() {
        
        const cartItemsList = this.props.cart.map(function(cartArr) {
            return (
                <Card key={cartArr._id}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <h6>{cartArr.title}</h6>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <h6>USD {cartArr.price}</h6>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <h6>qty. goes here</h6>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <ButtonGroup style={{minWidth:'300px'}}>
                                <Button
                                    variant = "default"
                                    size    = "small">
                                    -
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    variant = "default"
                                    size    = "small">
                                    +
                                </Button>
                                <span>     </span>
                                <Button
                                    onClick = {this.onClick(cartArr._id)}
                                    variant = "danger"
                                    size    = "small">
                                    DELETE
                                </Button>
                            </ButtonGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Card>
            )
        })

        return (
            <Card>
                {cartItemsList}
            </Card>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is some further reading if you don't want to bind it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-bind-or-inline-arrow-functions-inside-render-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your syntax

```
onClick = {this.onClick(cartArr._id)}
```

the function gets called immediately, not on-click.

You'll need

```
onClick = {() => this.onClick(cartArr._id)}
```

instead.

Anyway, with modern ES there's no need to manually bind things; use arrow functions instead.

Here's how I'd write your component (if it had to be a class component, not a function component):

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
  // Arrow functions are automagically bound
  onDelete = (_id) => {
    const { cart } = this.props;
    const cartWithoutGivenId = cart.filter((item) => item._id !== _id);
    const cartAfterDelete = { books: cartWithoutGivenId };
    this.props.deleteFromCart(cartAfterDelete);
  };

  render() {
    const { cart } = this.props;
    if (!cart.length) {
      return <div>Empty Cart</div>;
    }

    const cartItemsList = cart.map((item) => (
      <Card key={item._id}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <h6>{item.title}</h6>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <h6>USD {item.price}</h6>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <h6>qty. goes here</h6>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <ButtonGroup style={{ minWidth: "300px" }}>
              <Button variant="default" size="small">
                -
              </Button>
              <Button variant="default" size="small">
                +
              </Button>
              <Button
                onClick={() => this.onDelete(item._id)}
                variant="danger"
                size="small"
              >
                DELETE
              </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Card>
    ));

    return <Card>{cartItemsList}</Card>;
  }
}
```

## edit

For completeness, here's a pair of function components for this:

```
const CartItem = ({ item, onDelete }) => (
  <Card>
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <h6>{item.title}</h6>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <h6>USD {item.price}</h6>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <h6>qty. goes here</h6>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <ButtonGroup style={{ minWidth: "300px" }}>
          <Button variant="default" size="small">
            -
          </Button>
          <Button variant="default" size="small">
            +
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => onDelete(item._id)}
            variant="danger"
            size="small"
          >
            DELETE
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Card>
);

const Cart = ({ cart, deleteFromCart }) => {
  const onDelete = React.useCallback(
    (_id) => {
      const cartWithoutGivenId = cart.filter((item) => item._id !== _id);
      const cartAfterDelete = { books: cartWithoutGivenId };
      deleteFromCart(cartAfterDelete);
    },
    [cart],
  );

  if (!cart.length) {
    return <div>Empty Cart</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Card>
      {cart.map((item) => (
        <CartItem key={item._id} item={item} onDelete={onDelete} />
      ))}
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 onClick = {this.onClick(cartArr._id)}
```

change this line to

```
 onClick = {() => this.onClick(cartArr._id)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use currying.

When you write `this.onClick(cartArr._id)` it evaluates to undefined but it expects to get a callback function. So you need to return a function from onDelete, like this:

```
onDelete(id) {
    return function() {
         //On delete logic
    }
}
```

By the way, you can avoid binding the callback by using class properties and arrow functions(https://medium.com/quick-code/react-quick-tip-use-class-properties-and-arrow-functions-to-avoid-binding-this-to-methods-29628aca2e25)

Hope that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers I'd like to add explanation **why** your code throws `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined".` error.

You define `map` callback as regular function (not an arrow function) and according to [`map` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> If a thisArg parameter is provided, it will be used as callback's this
> value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as its this value.

So `this` inside your `map` callback is `undefined`, that's why you get an error. Although `onClick` function is correctly 'binded' you can't access this function because `this` inside `map` callback doesn't point to component instance. To fix it you can use an arrow function as `map` callback instead of regular function (because inside arrow function `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope is used).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Cleared a lot of things up :)

Comment: @PandasHelp You're welcome ;) Just please upvote my answer ;)