# How to I access DOM element using 'this' keyword in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In vanilla Javascript I can access 'this' keyword in event listeners like this:

```
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="test(this)">Click Me</button>
    <script>
      function test(t) {
        console.log(t); //this 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

or like this

```
  <body>
    <button id="test" type="button">Click Me</button>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("test").onclick = function () {
        console.log(this);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```

But how do i access DOM element using 'this' keyword in react event listener

```
export default function Button() {
  function test() {
    console.log(this); //undefined
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={test} id="test" type="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
}
```

I know I can access the target element using 'event' object. But I'm curious whether it is possible to use 'this' in react event listener

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be? What higher level problem are you trying to solve? Why can't you use the event target?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get object data and target element from onClick event in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576198/get-object-data-and-target-element-from-onclick-event-in-react-js)

Comment: @charlietfl this = element that is attached to the listener. I'm not trying to solve any higher level problem. Just curious.

Comment: Short answer then is no ... `this` will not be bound to the element

Comment: @kmoser Thanks for the reply. No .This is used in that question because they are using class components instead of functional components

Comment: @charlietfl Thank again for the reply. So there isn't an equivalent for the vanilla code in react?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with this that you can't do with currentTarget in event object?

Comment: @charlietfl As I already told you. I just wanted to know if there is any equivalent to that vanilla code in react. Nothing more. I'm sorry if I seem annoying

Comment: Not annoying but the answer is no

Comment: @charlietfl That's what I was looking for, a clear yes or no. Thanks you for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 1):

Pass a parameter to get the event argument.

e.g:

```
function test(event) {
    console.log(event.target); // returns the element which trigered the event
    console.log(event.currentTarget); // returns the element that the event listener is attached to.
 }
```

But if you want to don't want to do it this way, you can use the `querySelector` method inside the event too.

```
   const element = document.querySelector("#test");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already mentioned in the question that i know how to access target element using event object. I just want to know if it possible access dom element using 'this' keyword in react event listener

Comment: Don't think there's a way, this doesn't bind to the same thing it does with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` to access DOM nodes in React.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

function Button() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  function test() {
    console.log(buttonRef.current); 
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={test} id="test" type="button" ref={buttonRef}>
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
}
```

Read more about `ref` here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking whether an equivalent to 'this' keyword in the vanilla code exists in react. Turns out it doesn't