# Trouble accessing props in callback function of Google Login using react-google-login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm using [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) in my react-redux project and having trouble accessing the props for the component in which this login button exists. I used [react-facebook-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login) in a similar way and it works fine - however, `console.log(this)` in the `loginGoogle()` function prints 'undefined' whereas it printed the Javascript object representing the whole `Login` component in my similar `loginFacebook()` method. Any ideas as to how I can access this.props in `loginGoogle()`?

In my Login component:

```
//all needed import statements

class Login extends Component {

  loginGoogle(response) {
    console.log(response);
    this.props.loginGoogleRequest(response.profileObj.email, response.accessToken, response.tokenObj.expires_in)
  }

  render() {
    <GoogleLogin
      clientId="{client id here}"
      onSuccess={this.loginGoogle}
      className="custom-google-btn"
    />
  }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    loginGoogleRequest: (email, accessToken, expiresIn) => {
      //some code that isn't being reached
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

I trimmed a lot of the fat out of this class in order to make it more readable - please let me know if it would help if I included more code in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change `loginGoogle` definition  to Arrow function:
`loginGoogle(response) {` => `loginGoogle = (response) => {`

[An arrow function does not create its own "this", the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Or you may bind `loginGoogle` method, refer to this answer:
[Why JSX props should not use arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-jsx-props-should-not-use-arrow-functions)