# How to handle event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple hello world code:

```
import React from 'react';

class ShoppingList extends React.Component {

    getComponent(event) {
        console.log('li item clicked!');
        event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="shopping-list">
                <h1>This is props name: {this.props.name}</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick={this.getComponent.bind(this)}>Component 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

module.exports = ShoppingList;
```

When I click on `<li>Component 1</li>` nothing happens.

Why? Page is rendered successfully. No errors,
everything
is ok, but handler not working.

`FULL EXAMPLE`:

Node server:
app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var routes = require('./routes/index')

app.use('/', routes);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 9080);

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log(__dirname + '/public/');
    console.log('STARTED');
});
```

route:
index.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {name:"AHOJ"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';


var ShoppingList = require('./components/ShoppingList');

class IndexComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getComponent = this.getComponent.bind(this);
    }

    getComponent(event) {
        console.log('li item clicked!');
        event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <DefaultLayout name={this.props.name}>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick={this.getComponent}>Component 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </DefaultLayout>

        )
    }
};

module.exports = IndexComponent;
```

master.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');

class MasterLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <html lang="eng">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />

                    <title>{this.props.name}</title>
                    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald" />
                    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/main.css" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    {this.props.children}
                </body>
            </html>
        )
    }
};

module.exports = MasterLayout;
```

I hope, this code is clear for you, its hello world project. In full example is class `ShoppingList` : `IndexComponent`.

I read some tutorials, and I thinks, my code is correct, page is rendered successfully. No errors,
everything
is ok, but handler not working.

`<li>` have **not** data-reactid

Comment: I created this fiddle with your code and it seems to work as you expect https://jsfiddle.net/ay15ezyx/

Comment: You sure? Works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/mkk7fksw/

Comment: Yeah i am sure, I am using 15.6.1v

Comment: Then we'll need more information since at least two people have a working version w/o any changes. (Take heed of where you `bind`, though, you don't really want to do it in the `render` method.)

Comment: I added full code.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't how you should structure your component. Do it like so:

```
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getComponent = this.getComponent.bind(this);
    }

    getComponent(event) {
        console.log('li item clicked!');
        event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="shopping-list">
                <h1>This is props name: {this.props.name}</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick={this.getComponent}>Component 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What I have done here is I have created a constructor for your component. The constructor calls [`super()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) so that it can use the `this` keyword.

> When used in a constructor, the super keyword appears alone and must be used before the this keyword can be used. This keyword can also be used to call functions on a parent object.

Then, it calls `.bind(this)` and binds `getComponent` to the component. Now the `onClick` handler can be changed to `onClick={this.getComponent}`. Moving the call to `.bind()` to the constructor offers a significant performance boost, since now the method is bound only once, instead of being bound over and over every time the component gets rendered.

**Extra tip:** change the name of `getComponent`'s argument from `event` to something else. `event` is not a reserved keyword in JS, but it *is* however a global in certain versions of IE. Pretty tricky bug to track down.

Comment: Just to point out, the _reason_ to use `bind()` in the constructor is that it's preferable to do it once when the component is initialized, instead of inside of `render()` which will redundantly bind and re-bind the function every time `render` is run.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, still same problem. Not working. Constructor is called successfully, but handler not working, I am missing data-reactid in dom.

Comment: @stybl still not working, console is clear without errors and logs.

Comment: @praeslai The problem is not related to the component. This code works properly. The problem is somewhere else. Try creating a new react project and adding everything to it bit by bit, testing along the way. When the handler stops working, you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: `this.testMethod = this.test.bind(this);` then call `this.testMethod();` works sucesfully

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, you can also use stateless functional components and use a method stored in a constant:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const clickHandler = e => {
  console.log(`${e.target} \n element clicked!!! \n -------`);
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li style={{border:"solid 1px"}}
        onClick={clickHandler}
      >Click Me</li>
    </ul>
    <h2 onClick={clickHandler}>I'm a header</h2>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If you click on the `<li>` the console will show:

```
[object HTMLLIElement] 
 element clicked!!! 
 -------
```

If you click on the header it'll show:

```
[object HTMLHeadingElement] 
 element clicked!!! 
 -------
```

But of course if you need to extend the component class you can use it, although is not necessary to create the constructor if you use the target instead of current target:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Here's the code without the constructor:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {

  clickHandler(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li style={{border:"solid 1px"}}
            onClick={this.clickHandler}
          >Click Me</li>
        </ul>
        <h2 onClick={this.clickHandler}>I'm a header</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As you can see it works in both cases:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nZY3W5x0p

Answer (score 0):

Change your li to:

```
<li onClick={() => this.getComponent}>Component 1</li>
```

This way it will reference it properly when actually clicked, and not when rendered.

Comment: You should take a look at [Why you shouldn't use inline arrow functions in JSX props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-jsx-props-should-not-use-arrow-functions). It is a bad practice and will cause you problems. Hurt performance. Causes increased work for the garbage collector and breaks `PureComponent` shallow compare.

Comment: (Oops, I missed the inline arrow function--my bad. But this is just a fancy way of doing the `bind` from the OP's source, so makes no difference.)

Comment: Using an inline arrow function makes a big difference when it comes to performance.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Appreciate the link.