# Change route onClick of div react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, routes

I need to wrap a navigational component in React in a div that acts as a link/a (I have an `<a></a>` nested in the nav item already and can nest another `<a></a>` within. I need re-route the user to a new route on click of this outer most div that is acting as a wrapper. I have multiple navigational sections and want to use something like an `onClick={this.handleNavClick(newRoute)}` but am not having any success. I am console logging the correct linkPath but nothing happens on click.

Here is my function:

```
  handleNavClick(linkPath) {
    console.log(linkPath)
    let currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    currentPath =  window.location.linkPath;
  },
```

Here is an example of me trying to re-route from a nav section:

```
 getNavItem() {
        const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
        const reportPath = "/reporting";

        return (
          <div onClick={this.handleNavClick(dashboardsPath)}>
            <li id="nav-item-view" className={ classNames({"active": currentPath === reportPath}, "sidebar-item")}>
              <div className="active-carat"></div>
            </li>
          </div>
        );
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
   onClick={() => {this.handleNavClick(dashboardsPath)}}
```

Comment: I'd recommend [against this though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-jsx-props-should-not-use-arrow-functions)

Comment: @Ezz yes, you are right. But Facebook confirmes this method in it's docs. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html so it's ok if we have no issues with performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `onClick` accepts a function, but here you're passing the result of a function.

You can do something like this

```
 getNavItem() {
    const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    const reportPath = "/reporting";

    const handleNavClick = () => {
      let currentPath = window.location.pathname;
      currentPath =  dashboardPath;
    };

    return (
      <div onClick={handleNavClick}>
        <li id="nav-item-view" className={ classNames({"active": currentPath === reportPath}, "sidebar-item")}>
          <div className="active-carat"></div>
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  },
```

However I'd avoid creating a handler on every render for performance reasons. You should instead create a NavItem component with it's own `handleNavClick` method and `dashboardPath` prop.