# How to pass parameter in a function on onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to make a component which receiving a function as a props. i want to pass some value into function while calling it:

```
class Course extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                 <div id="courses">
                      <p onClick={this.props.sumPrice}>{this.props.name}<b>{this.props.price}</b></p>
                 </div>
             </div>
        );
     }
 }
```

`sumPrice` is a function define in parent component and its need a value.
This is my `sumPrice` function and parent class constructor code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        active: false,
        total: 0
    };

    this.sumPrice = this.sumPrice.bind(this);
}

sumPrice(price) {
    this.setState({ total: this.state.total + price });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the closure, arrow function in render handles such situations exactly how it is needed:

```
<div id="courses">
    <p
      onClick={() => this.props.sumPrice(this.props.price)}
    >
      { this.props.name }<b>{ this.props.price }</b>
    </p>
</div>
```

While it works as expected, unfortunately it comes at cost ot performance penalty [Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677798). The impact does not have to be dramatic problem but should be generally avoided.

---

The optimal solution is to use the functions which are not recreated on each re-render, like class method:

```
class Course extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
    }

    onClick () {
      const { sumPrice, price } = this.props

      sumPrice(price)
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                 <div id="courses">
                      <p onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.name}<b>{this.props.price}</b></p>
                 </div>
             </div>
        )
     }
  }
```

Avoiding performance issues.

Comment: this solution is giving Cannot read property 'props' of undefined error

Comment: The second solution also needs manually binding eg in constructor like it was in `this.sumPrice.bind(this)`. `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)`