# unable to display state variable inside <h1>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
export default class player extends React.Component {
constructor(...args) {
super(...args);
this.state = {
  shoot: 0
};
}
```

`shoot`is the variable i'm trying to change in the function shooter, and display later in `<h1>`.

```
shooter() {
this.setState({ shoot: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3)) });
console.log("hello");
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.state.shoot}</h1>
    <button onClick={() => this.shooter}>shoot it</button>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

the `<h1>` is not changing as the state changes, won't the state change as `shooter()` fires? and doesn't it update the `<h1>`.

any help much appreciated. :-)

Comment: `() => this.shooter()`

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
<button onClick={() => this.shooter}>shoot it</button>
```

To

```
<button onClick={() => this.shooter()}>shoot it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind your class method `shooter` in your constructor, in order to use it like this `onClick={this.shooter}`.

You can find a further explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind).

```
 export default class player extends React.Component {
      constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {
          shoot: 0
        };
        this.shooter = this.shooter.bind(this);
      }

      render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.shoot}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.shooter}>shoot it</button>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }
```