# React hooks useCallback with parameters inside loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn about the hooks functionality, however I can't quite seem to figure out how I'm supposed to use the function `useCallback` properly. As far as I understand from the rules about hooks I'm supposed to call them top-level and not within logic (such as loops). Which leads me to be quite confused how I'm supposed to implement `useCallback` on components that are rendered from a loop.

Take a look at the following example snippet where I create 5 buttons with an `onClick` handler that prints the number of the button to the console.

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const onClick = (key) => {
    console.log("You clicked: ", key);
  };
  
  return(
    <div>
      {
        _.times(5, (key) => {
          return (
            <button onClick={() => onClick(key)}>
              {key}
            </button>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};
console.log("hello there");

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
</div>
```

Right now it creates a new function instance everytime the Example renders due to my use of the arrow function within the `<button onClick={() => onClick(key)}>`, which I do because I want the `onClick` function to know which button called it. I thought I could prevent this with the new react hooks functionality by using `useCallback`, however if I apply it to the `const onClick` then it would still create a new instance every render because of the inline arrow function needed to give the `key` parameter, and I'm not allowed to apply it to the render within a loop as far as I know (especially if the loop order might change right?).

So how would I go about implementing `useCallback` in this scenario while keeping the same functionality? Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The simple answer here is, you probably shouldn't use `useCallback` here.  The point of `useCallback` is to pass the same function instance to optimized components (e.g. `PureComponent` or `React.memo`ized components) to avoid unnecessary rerenders.

You're not dealing with optimized components in this case (or most cases, I'd suspect) so there's not really a reason to memoize callbacks like with `useCallback`.

---

Supposing the memoization is important, though, the best solution here is probably to use a single function instead of five: instead of a unique function for each button carries the `key` by closure, you can attach the `key` to the element:

```
<button data-key={key}>{key}</button>
```

And then read the key from the `event.target.dataset["key"]` inside a single click handler:

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  // Single callback, shared by all buttons
  const onClick = React.useCallback((e) => {
    // Check which button was clicked
    const key = e.target.dataset["key"]
    console.log("You clicked: ", key);
  }, [/* dependencies */]);
  
  return(
    <div>
      {
        _.times(5, (key) => {
          return (
            <button data-key={key} onClick={onClick}>
              {key}
            </button>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};
console.log("hello there");

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
</div>
```

---

All that being said, it is possible to memoize multiple functions in a single hook.  `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`, and `useMemo` can be used to memoize multiple functions at once:

```
const clickHandlers = useMemo(() => _.times(5, key => 
  () => console.log("You clicked", key)
), [/* dependencies */]);
```

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const clickHandlers = React.useMemo(() => _.times(5, key => 
    () => console.log("You clicked", key)
  ), [/* dependencies */])
  
  return(
    <div>
      {
        _.times(5, (key) => {
          return (
            <button onClick={clickHandlers[key]}>
              {key}
            </button>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};
console.log("hello there");

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
</div>
```

Perhaps there's a case where that's useful, but in this case I would either leave it alone (and not worry about the optimization) or else use a single handler for each button.

Comment: The `data-*` attributes part of this answer is also provided in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#example-passing-params-using-data-attributes) for optimizing callback events for a large number of elements

Comment: OP didn't ask for opinions on when it's appropriate to useCallback. This is a non-answer.

Comment: @tshm001 They asked about "proper usage" and sometimes the proper usage is to not use it.  I did show how to memoize an array of callbacks (`useMemo` is the same purpose as `useCallback`).  If you've got a better answer, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a closure, and you can do so even with `useCallback`;

With your example:

```
const Example = (props) => {
  const handleClick = useCallback((key) => (event) => {
    console.log("You clicked: ", key);
  }, []);
  
  return(
    <div>
      {
        _.times(5, (key) => {
          return (
            <button onClick={handleClick(key)}>
              {key}
            </button>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

This example is simple without any need to refresh the `handleClick`, but be careful with your memoized functions though, they usually need to be updated if you use props *within* the closure. Update the `[]` accordingly.