# useCallback with args passed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization, usecallback

I have a [`<Tabs />` component](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/) in material-ui, that has a handler for changing mode. The on change has this signature (from the link):

> **Signature**:
>   `function(event: object, value: any) => void`
>   event: The event source of the callback
>   value: We default to the index of the child (number)

My implementation goes a little something like this:

```
<Tabs
  value={mode}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
  <Tab id="choice1" value="one" label="Choice 1" />
  <Tab id="choice2" value="two" label="Choice 2" />
</Tabs>
```

My `handleChange` function is just an arrow fn around a useState-like hook

```
const handleChangeMode = (event, newMode) => {
  setMode(newMode);
}
```

In an effort to avoid recreating this arrow fn each time, I've tried to do this:

```
const handleChangeMode = useCallback((event, newMode) => {
  setMode(newMode);
}, [setMode]);
```

but I noticed, that the thing that changes the most, the new mode isn't part of the deps, and thus would perhaps not behave properly? Then I conjured this monstrosity from my darkest dreams:

```
const handleChangeMode = useCallback((event, newMode) => {
  useCallback(() => setMode(newMode), [setMode, newMode])();
}, [setMode]);
```

***It's callbacks all the way down.***

Previously, this question ([React hooks useCallback with parameters inside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006061/react-hooks-usecallback-with-parameters-inside-loop)) suggested not to use `useCallback` in that scenario. But as this is something that could be called over and over, it seems like the place to do so. Also the example with `useMemo` doesn't get around that I want to depend on a variable passed into the hook, which I don't even think works in this example (e.g. I'm using the hook wrong, as well as not knowing how to use it for my example).

How do I get around this issue?

(Edit: in fact, I cannot nest the callback/memo hooks at all. so the last code example doesn't work, as I suspected)

Comment: The `newMode` is coming from the params. However, the `onChange` handler can't pass it. Please add the code of the component.

Comment: @OriDrori I've linked to the docs of the component, and given the onChange signature. Is that the one you meant?

Comment: The `event` and `newMode` params are passed by the component the calls the `onChange` handler. You don't have to include them in the dependencies of `useCallback`. Your 1st version (only one useCallback) is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You ask:**

> but I noticed, that the thing that changes the most, the new mode isn't part of the deps, and thus would perhaps not behave properly?

```
const handleChangeMode = useCallback((event, newMode) => {
  setMode(newMode);
}, [setMode]);
```

**Answer:** No, this code will behave properly. You need to add props to dependencies only if you use them directly from component. For example:

```
const { mode } = props;
const handleChangeMode = useCallback((event) => {
  setMode(mode);
}, [setMode, mode]);
```

In your case you get `newMode` as argument of a function. So you don't need to add it as a dependency.

Comment: Ahhh I'm memorising between renders, not between calls. I got it now, thanks.