# Performance difference between using arrow functions and partial application in render functions?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any performance difference (or other differences that make one better than the other) between

Using arrow functions in render functions:

```
<SomeElement
    onClick={() => this.updateSalesQuoteProgress(QuotationProgressState.Done)} 
/>

private updateSalesQuoteProgress = (progress: QuotationProgressState): void => {
    this.actionService.updateSalesQuoteProgress(this.props.project, progress);
};
```

Using partial application in render functions:

```
<SomeElement
    onClick={this.updateSalesQuoteProgress(QuotationProgressState.Installed)}
/>

private updateSalesQuoteProgress = (progress: QuotationProgressState): (() => void) => {
    return () => {
        this.actionService.updateSalesQuoteProgress(this.props.project, progress);
    };
};
```

If there is a difference, please explain why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the cases the returned function is created on every render which affects performance when you have a large application and a lot of such patterns.

The major problem will come when you have nested components as `PureComponent` or you implement  `shouldComponentUpdate` with `shallow` comparison of props and when you pass arrow functions as props, the shallow check in `PureComponent` fails causing performance issues.

Sample demo

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.onClick === nextProps.onClick) {
      console.log('same click');
    } else {
      console.log('different click');
    }
    
    if(this.props.onChange === nextProps.onChange) {
      console.log('same change');
    } else {
      console.log('different change');
    }
    return true;
  }
  click = () => {
    this.props.onClick('xyx');
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.click}>Click</button>
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prev => ({count: prev.count+ 1}));
    }, 1000)
  }
  handleClick = (id) => (value) => {
    console.log(id, value);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
  handleChange = (val) => {
    console.log(val)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div><Child onClick={this.handleClick(1)} onChange={() => this.handleChange(1)} count={this.state.count}/></div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

In order to avoid inline arrow function you can refer this post

[How to avoid bind or inline arrow functions inside render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-bind-or-inline-arrow-functions-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753)