# How to Prevent Child Component Re-Render when Parent state changes

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I have two stateless components and one stateful component. In my stateful component, I have a list of people and when I click one of them, it opens a modal. I basically store modal's state in stateful component and send the values as props to modal. So it changes states anytime it opens a model and re-renders everything.

How can I prevent my stateless classes to be re-rendered after I change state?

I have tried memo in my stateless components but no luck

Modal component

```
const modal = React.memo((props) => {

    return (
    <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.handleClose} aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
           centered>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={props.handleClose}>
                Close
            </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
    )
});

export default modal
```

Person Component

```
const person = React.memo((props) => {
    console.log("render");
    return (
        <article className="Person" onClick={props.clicked}>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <p style={{marginBottom: 0 + 'px', marginTop: 1 + 'rem'}}><b>{props.name}</b></p>
                        <div className="Organization-wrapper">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon className="Organization-icon" icon={faBuilding}/><p>{props.company}</p>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <div>
                            {
                                props.image ?
                                    <img src={props.image} height="50" width="50" className="Person-image"
                                         alt="avatar"/>
                                    : <svg height="50" width="50" className="Person-image">
                                        <rect fill="cornflowerblue" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50"/>
                                        <text
                                            fill="#ffffff"
                                            fontSize="20"
                                            textAnchor="middle"
                                            x="25"
                                            y="30">{props.first_char.toUpperCase()}</text>
                                    </svg>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </article>
    );
});
```

Stateful Component

```
class PersonList extends Component {

    state = {
        persons: [],
        show: false
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('')
            .then(response => {
                const result = response.data.data.slice(0, 5);
                this.setState({persons: result});
            });
    }

    personSelectedHandler = (id) => {
        this.showModal();
    };

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({ show: true });
    };

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    };

    render() {
        const persons = this.state.persons.map(person => {

            let avatar;
            if (person.picture_id != null) {
                avatar = person.picture_id.pictures["128"];
            }
            return <ListGroup>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Person
                        key={person.id}
                        name={person.name}
                        company={person.org_id.name}
                        first_char={person.first_char}
                        image={avatar}
                        clicked={() => this.personSelectedHandler(person.id)}
                    />
                </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
        });

        return (

            <div className="Wrapper">
                <Modal show = {this.state.show} handleClose = {this.hideModal}/>
                <Header/>
                <div className="Breadcrumb">
                    <h4 className="Breadcrumb-text"><b>People's List</b></h4>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
                {persons}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default PersonList;
```

Comment: use shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle to prevent re-rendering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Person
    ...
    clicked={() => this.personSelectedHandler(person.id)}
/>
```

This will define a new function reference for `props.clicked` on each re-render of the parent function.  This will cause the props for `Person` to be changed on each render, causing `Person` to also re-render.

Since you're not currently using `id` in `personSelectedHandler`, you could just omit the argument and keep the function reference constant:

```
clicked={this.personSelectedHandler}
```

If you end up needing the `id` context, you might want to consider some use of the parents' state to achieve what you're after instead, if you *really* want to avoid re-rendering.

You could also convert `Person` to a (pure) class component, and handle the callback from within that component.

Lastly, if push comes to shove and you absolutely must use this in-line arrow function, you could override `React.memo`'s comparison function, which is roughly analogous to defining `componentShouldUpdate` for class components.  [From the docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html)

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
}
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
}
export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

There might be another way I'm not aware of to make this work, but hopefully this helps you understand the issue to explore alternate solutions.  There's also some ideas and discussion here: [Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed my stateless function component to React.Component and used shouldComponentUpdate in it. I couldn't make it work with other options

Comment: No problem, it's kind of an annoying use-case to deal with.  If you want to continue using functional components with `React.memo`, I clarified my answer for overriding React.memo's comparison function.  It should be approximately the same as defining `componentDidUpdate` (although it's expected to return the inverse; `true` if the component _shouldn't_ re-render).  I've never used it for this particular case though, and am not sure if there are any pitfalls I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

if you use hook you can use `useCallback()` method with `Recat.memo` together.
in your componenet :

```
const callBack = useCallback(() => this.personSelectedHandler(person.id),[person.id]);
```

`useCallback((person.id) => personSelectedHandler(person.id),[person.id]);` always returns the same function instance as long as `person.id`is the same.
then:

```
<Person
    ...
    clicked={callBack}
/>
```