# React is calling function unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is my Login component:

```
const Login = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");
    const [pass, setPass] = useState("");

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Login</p>
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setUser(e.target.value);
                }}
            />
            <input
                type="password"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setPass(e.target.value);
                }}
            />


            <button onClick={submit(user, pass)}>
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

It renders on my webpage, but it calls the `submit()` function whenever I input to these two: text and password. Looking at my code, I've only set the onClick to call the `submit` function.

Is there something wrong with my code?

EDIT: Removed classNames for easier viewing

Comment: Another option is to turn your `submit` function in to a currying function like so - `const submit = (user, pass) => () => {...}`

Comment: Worked for me, but I think I'll be using the () => {...} in the onClick since I'll be confused for having double argument receptors in my function. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `submit` function on every render. onClick takes a function, but you are directly calling a function.

```
<button onClick={submit(user, pass)}>
   Submit
</button>
```

will be replaced by

```
<button onClick={()=>submit(user, pass)}>
   Submit
</button>
```

Comment: [Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36677733/7509065)

Comment: Surely @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, But performance matters only when you measure it. User did not asked for performance issue. He was having trouble with basic code. He will eventually encounter performance issue down the line and then he will ask about performance.

Comment: But why teach bad habits that we'll have to correct later? Why not teach the right way the first time? It's one extra call to `useCallback`, and the code in the question is already using other hooks, so it's not like it's a new concept altogether.

Comment: That is not bad habit @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. If inline functions are this bad then react shouldnt have supported them at all.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a premature optimization. And they try to ban it: there's a linter rule called `jsx-no-lambda`. They can't do more than that since they're just a UI library and not the language.

Comment: But that is just a linter rule. Here is what Michael Jackson has to say ```Just bugs me when people lean back in their armchair and go "eh, that code looks like it could be slow to me" w/out measuring anything.```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```js
const Login = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");
    const [pass, setPass] = useState("");

    const onSubmit = () => {
       submit(user,pass)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Login</p>
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setUser(e.target.value);
                }}
            />
            <input
                type="password"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setPass(e.target.value);
                }}
            />


            <button onClick={onSubmit}>
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```