# React - Pass props through function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which renders the following:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className = "events card" >
      <div key = {each.id}> 
        <ul>
          <li className = "card-text">Venue Name: {each.name} </li>
          <li className = "card-text">Country: {each.country} </li>
          <li className = "card-text">City: {each.city} </li>
          <li className = "card-text">Date: {each.date}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a onClick = {this.addToFavourites.bind(this)}>
        <Button text = "Add to Favourites"/>
      </a>
    </div
  );
}

addToFavourites() {
... do something
}
```

When I call addToFavourites, I want to pass the name, country, city and date to this function as it is going through an array of events so I don't know how else the function will do what it's supposed to do with the selected data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THis is what you can do:

```
<a onClick = {() => this.addToFavourites(each)}><Button text = "Add to Favourites"/></a>
```

This will ensure that the object will be passed to the `addToFavourites` method.

And from there, you can access the properties from `each` in the method itself.

```
addToFavourites(each) {
  const { name, country, city, date } = each;
  // do the rest 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @wentjun is very much correct. I just want to propose an alternative solution.

You can pass the arguments you want to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).
But you should also know both these practices are not advisable. Read more here [Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind)

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div className = "events card" >
      <div key = {each.id}> 
        <ul>
          <li className = "card-text">Venue Name: {each.name} </li>
          <li className = "card-text">Country: {each.country} </li>
          <li className = "card-text">City: {each.city} </li>
          <li className = "card-text">Date: {each.date}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a onClick = {this.addToFavourites.bind(this, each)}>
        <Button text = "Add to Favourites"/>
      </a>
    </div
  );
}

addToFavourites(each) {
  const { name, country, city, date } = each;
  // do the rest 
}
```