# React Native Typescript Formik cast event type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, type-conversion, formik

In the Formik documentation for React Native it has an example form:

```
<Formik initialValues={{ email: '' }} onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}>
  {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={handleChange('email')} onBlur={handleBlur('email')} value={values.email} />
      <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
    </View>
  )}
</Formik>
```

This, however, gives me a Typescript error:

```
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<ButtonProps>): Button', gave the following error.
  Type '(e?: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(ev: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeTouchEvent>) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'e' and 'ev' are incompatible.
      Type 'NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeTouchEvent>' is not assignable to type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>'.
```

Given that I am getting the handleSubmit function from destructuring, how can I cast the type of event correctly?

Note: I know I can do this, but I have read that this will cause additional renders in React:

```
<Button onPress={(e) => handleSubmit(e as any)} title="Submit" />
```

Comment: "but I have read that this will cause additional renders in React" can you explain this?

Comment: Where the component `Button` comes from?

Comment: Button comes from react native: `import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';`

Comment: Regarding re-renders, see here for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677798/4553162

Comment: About your explanation, it depends if you are using functional or class component

Comment: On reading a bit more, I think in this case using an inline arrow function is ok. I.e. I'll stick to this: `<Button onPress={(e) => handleSubmit(e as any)} title="Submit" />`

Comment: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/376/
It seems that this error is know for quite some time.
To avoid rerenders and not get errors you can try:
onPress={handleSubmit as any}
This is not ideal, but it will prevent unnecessary rerenders.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's not the best but you can do something like this

```
  <Button
     onPress={handleSubmit as (values: any) => void} // <= add this
     title="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Mina Makar's answer I resolved the type error the following way:

```
<Button
  onPress={
    handleSubmit as (values:
      GestureResponderEvent |
      React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> |
      undefined) => void
  }
/>
```