# I failed to compile pancakeswap frontend repo on localhost

Tags: reactjs

I tried to compile frontend repo of Pancakeswap but I see "Failed to compile" error when I enter `npm run start` command.

Here is the error I see on localhost:3000

```
src\components\Modal\ModalInput.tsx
  Line 13:3:  'placeholder' PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types

src\components\PageSection\CurvedDivider.tsx
  Line 7:3:  'svgFill' PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types

src\components\Toast\DescriptionWithTx.tsx
  Line 9:3:  'description' PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types

src\views\AddLiquidity\index.tsx
  Line 242:9:  JSX props should not use functions  react/jsx-no-bind

src\views\FarmAuction\components\AuctionDetailsCard\AuctionSchedule.tsx
  Line 18:3:  'showForClosedAuction' PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types

src\views\Home\components\CompositeImage.tsx
  Line 74:3:  'animate' PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types

src\views\Pools\components\PoolCard\CardFooter\index.tsx
  Line 13:3:  'totalCakeInVault' PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types

src\views\Profile\components\ConfirmProfileCreationModal.tsx
  Line 18:3:  'userName' PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types

src\views\RemoveLiquidity\index.tsx
  Line 378:93:  JSX props should not use functions  react/jsx-no-bind
  Line 447:48:  JSX props should not use functions  react/jsx-no-bind
  Line 447:73:  JSX props should not use functions  react/jsx-no-bind
  Line 637:19:  JSX props should not use functions  react/jsx-no-bind
```

Comment: Can you show the `Line 378` of `src\views\RemoveLiquidity\index.tsx` file ? it could be the same error in other lines as well. Check whether this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind

Comment: Hey @KavinduVIndika.

`<Button disabled={!(approval === ApprovalState.APPROVED || signatureData !== null)} onClick={onRemove}>`

This is the 378th line of the file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.