# Using inline arrow function in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I know it is bad practice to use inline arrow function in react component.

But what should I do when my function has arguments ?

e.g. in `CustomInput` I have a function to handle focus state and has an argument. I use it in onBlur and onFocus and pass parameter to it.

```
const CustomInput = () => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

  const handleFocus = (isFocus) => {
    /**
     * Some Conditions to check
     */
    setFocused(isFocus);
  };

  return (
    <input
      onFocus={() => handleFocus(true)}
      onBlur={() => handleFocus(false)}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: "I know it is bad practice to use inline arrow function in react component." -> who said that?

Comment: @giorgimoniava refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind

Comment: that is an old question and doesn't apply to hooks. Besides performance is mentioned which in most of the cases won't be noticeable

Comment: @giorgimoniava So you are saying it may cause some small performance issues. By accept this, how can improve it?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what your problem is

Comment: @giorgimoniava Think we are very sensitive and do not want to have any performance problems, even small :)

Comment: using arrow functions in Hooks is fine, see the official docs example even starts with one: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @giorgimoniava OK, tnx :))

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the standards and conventions your company/project uses. Sometimes, inline arrow-functions are permitted, other times it is a strict rule to define a function, in which case you usually use a `handleEvent` template.

In the case of a strict rule against inline function declarations, you have several solutions:

1. Avoid this problem entirely by refraining from [Boolean traps](https://ariya.io/2011/08/hall-of-api-shame-boolean-trap).
2. Rename `handleFocus` and then create `handleFocus` and `handleBlur` functions that call that function.
3. Use a [Reducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) that `handleFocus` and `handleBlur` will call, each with a different action. (In my opinion, not the best solution for such a small-scale problem)

Comment: For solution #1 that you mentioned, how would refactor the `onFocus` and `onBlur` props? Define separate `setFocused` and `setBlurred` functions that take no arguments and just set the `focused` state to true or false within the implementation respectively?

Comment: No, the second you click (or tab) inside/outside of the element it triggers

Answer (score 1):

The input focus will either be true or false. You can just pass in the handler function to the listeners, and because you know there will always only be two states, you can simply update the state with the inversion of the current state boolean.

If there are other arguments you think you'll need to pass in I tend to attach the data to [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the element, and then destructure them from the dataset in the handler.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

  function handleFocus(e) {
    const { text } = e.target.dataset;
    console.log(text);
    setFocus(!focus);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Focused? ${focus}`);
  }, [focus]);

  return (
    <input
      data-text="This is an example"
      onFocus={handleFocus}
      onBlur={handleFocus}
    />
  );

};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: That was just an example, think argument accept many values.

Comment: why use data attribute when you can just use as callback `(e)=>handleFocus(e,"This is an example")`?

Comment: I find data attributes more expressive and readable.

Comment: Fine, also his point about arrow functions confuses me, even official react docs start with arrow function in example:https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: This is a very situation-specific answer, I think OP intended to receive a bit broader solution.

Comment: It answers the question that was asked @EldarB. If we all answered questions that weren't asked there would be mayhem.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the question itself gave this code solely as an example, and not as the only problem to focus on.

Comment: But that's not how this site works. We solely look at the code at hand and help debug that, otherwise questions would be too broad, and answers unfocused. It's situation-specific because that was the situation expressed in the question.

Comment: OP literally commented on this answer saying exactly what I said, you just ignored it so I decided to remind you. You act as if that comment isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I correctly understood your question, but here is my take:

It is just about how to pass params and still get handlers to work by returning another function

```
const CustomInput = () => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

  const handleFocus = (isFocus) => () => {
    /**
     * Some Conditions to check
     */
    setFocused(isFocus);
  };

  return (
    <input
      onFocus={handleFocus(true)}
      onBlur={handleFocus(false)}
    />
  );
};
```

As for optimisations:

If your component re-renders, your function will be "re-created" either way. Its there you need to decide if optimisation is really needed (no premature optimisations) and if you need it that much it is accomplished by other ways:

1. extracting function from component
2. using useCallback (useMemo)
3. wrapping component in React.memo()

etc...

You can play with an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-greider-oph1f?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score -2):

use the function after binding `this` to `null` like:

```
<input
      onFocus={handleFocus.bind(null,true)}
      onBlur={handleFocus.bind(null,false)}
/>
```

Comment: How is that at all helpful?